# Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I'm working on a `book` using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)&[`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) and want to include chapters (with their numbers and names, but *no page number*) in the list of figures, *if and only if* they contain figures. Manually adding

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {\thechapter} {#1}}{} }}
```

after each chapter works (`#1` is the chaptername), and I could also fix the alignment (not part of MWE),
but I couldn't append this to `\chapter`.

Can I get `titletoc` to include chapters into the list of figures?
Or how do I modify `\chapter` to add themselves to the lof?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles,psfloats,clearempty,newlinetospace]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\vspace{1cm}\thechapter}{0.5cm}{}[]

%\let\Oldchapter\chapter
%\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\Oldchapter{#1}\addtocontents{lof}%
%{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {\thechapter} {#1}}{} }}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First}

\chapter{Has Figures}
\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The code below illustrates a possible solution; the basic idea is to let the `figure` environment do the job and decide if the chapter info will be written to the ToC; this is accomplished by using `\AtBeginEnvironment` (from the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) or [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) packages); whenever the figure environment is used in the document, it will examine a boolean flag; if the boolean is false, then it adds the chapter information to the LoF and sets the boolean to true; otherwise, it does not add any information.

The `\@chapter` command was also modified to reset the boolean and to globally store the information about the corresponding title and number; this information will then be used when writing to the LoF.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % or xpatch

\makeatletter
% initial definitions of the chapter info (name and number)
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}%
  {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}

% the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, 
% it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \iftoggle{noFigs}{
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
    }{}
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

\chapter{Another Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The list of figures obtained:

[image]

#### Remarks:

1. The initial solution was simplified thanks to a comment by **Markus Schmassmann**.
2. As **lockstep** mentions in his comment, further refinement would be needed in case one uses a continuous figure numbering scheme. *Done* by **Markus Schmassmann**.
3. When using `hyperref`, the package must be loaded *after* the lines `\apptocmd{\@chapter}...`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You should add a hint that further refinement would be needed in case one uses a continuous figure numbering scheme. Anyway, great answer!

Comment: This be simplified by deleting `\newcommand*\l@chapterinfo` & `\def\@nodottedtocline` and replacing `\addcontentsline` by `\addtocontents{lof}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{} }`.  `titletoc` takes care of the formating.

Comment: @MarkusSchmassmann: you're right. I incorporated your suggestion into my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I forgot to `\protect` some commands, otherwise the `lof` won't be human readable.

Comment: @MarkusSchmassmann: yes. I've also added an extra pair of braces to the `\addtocontents` to make it compatible with `hyperref`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: solved **lockstep**'s figure numbering issue using a boolean and included ref to xpatch.

Comment: @MarkusSchmassmann: the code already does it, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Is there a not too complicated way to increase the penalty for pagebreaks between chapters and figures?

Comment: I'm unsure if this is something unique to the packages I'm using, but I've noticed that if I don't include all placement hints (i.e., any ordering of `tbph`), then numbering in lists of figures/tables is messed up (e.g., fig 5.1 [not including placement hint for `h`] will show up in chapter 4's list of figures) --- if you're having this issue, it's a fairly quick fix to just add placement hints to the floats in question.

Answer (score 12):

Another way to handle this that doesn't require individually modifying each environment you need (figure, table, algorithm, listing, ...) is to instead patch `\addcontentsline`. A slight modification of Gonzalo's solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\thischaptertitle{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}}{}{}

\newcommand{\DeclareDividedList}[1]%
  {\newcounter{#1@chapter}\setcounter{#1@chapter}{0}}

\pretocmd{\addcontentsline}%
  {\ifltxcounter{#1@chapter}%
   {%
     \ifnumgreater{\thechapter}{\value{#1@chapter}}{%
       \setcounter{#1@chapter}{\thechapter}%
       \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}%
         {\protect\numberline {\thechapter} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
     }{}%
   }{}%
  }{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareDividedList{lof}
\DeclareDividedList{lot}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures but no Tables}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Tables but no Figures}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures and Tables}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This gives you chapter headings in both the list of figures and list of tables:

[image: list of figures example]
[image: list of tables example]

If you don't use the `\DeclareDividedList` for one of them, say `lot`, then the counter `\lot@chapter` isn't created, and the `\ifltxcounter` switch will fail and the added code is not run when creating lines in the list of tables; the list will be typeset exactly as normal, without chapter headers.

Just as with the previous examples, this tends to break with unnumbered chapters.

Comment: Would you see the problem what I have for appendices, in the following question:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549556/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-fails-for-appendices

...All this time after !

Comment: You need to use `\value{chapter}` instead of `\thechapter` when using `\ifnumgreater ` and `\setcounter` (and watch out for the chapter numbering resetting in the appendix).

Answer (score 2):

More of a comment than an answer actually (sorry, new account no cred' yet). With minor changes, the code proposed also works for adding chapters in a LoT by similarly modding the `table` environment.

```
\documentclass{book} \usepackage{etoolbox}  % or xpatch

\makeatletter % initial definitions of the chapter info (name and number) \def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{} \newtoggle{noTabs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}%   {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\toggletrue{noTabs}}{}{}

% the table environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command,  % it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF \AtBeginDocument{%   \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \iftoggle{noTabs}{
      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
    }{}   }% }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents \listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction with no Tables}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Tables} \begin{table} \caption{caption text} \end{table} \begin{table} \caption{caption text} \end{table}

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Tables}

\chapter{Another Test Chapter with Tables} \begin{table} \caption{caption text} \end{table} \begin{table} \caption{caption text} \end{table} \begin{table} \caption{caption text} \end{table} \begin{table} \caption{caption text} \end{table} \begin{table} \caption{caption text} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I can't post a snapshot either...

Anyway, great post, exactly what I was looking for!