# Add both part and chapter titles to list of figures with formatting and line wrapping

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titletoc

In a table of contents style list of figures I would like to combine the appearance of each of these questions.

[Part title in list of figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103926/part-title-in-list-of-figures-and-tables)

[Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc)

> Part title
>
> Chapter title
>
> List of Figures in this chapter
>
> Chapter title
>
> List of Figures in this chapter
>
> Part title
>
> Chapter title
>
> List of Figures in this chapter
>
> Chapter title
>
> List of Figures in this chapter

I have tried to combine the parts, but in my MWE below, I don't seem to get the inclusion of the parts titles and I can't seem to change the formatting of these newly added titles.  I need to add a little more space between them and make them more visibly different from the titles of the figures I am referencing?

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}  % or xpatch
    \usepackage{bookmark}
    \usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter

    % initial definitions of the part info (name and number)
    \def\thisparttitle{}\def\thispartnumber{}
    \def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}

    \newtoggle{noFigs}
    \newtoggle{noTabs}

    \apptocmd{\@chapter}{\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}\global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}
    \apptocmd{\@part}{\gdef\thisparttitle{#1}\gdef\thispartnumber{\thepart}\global\toggletrue{noFigs}\global\toggletrue{noTabs}}{}{}

    % the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
            \iftoggle{noFigs}{
                \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{part}%
                    {\protect\numberline{\thisparttitle}}{}{3.2em} }
                \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
                    {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
                \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
            }{}
        }%
        \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
            \iftoggle{noTabs}{
                \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{part}%
                    {\protect\numberline{\thisparttitle}}{}{} }
                \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
                    {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
                \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
            }{}
        }%
    }


\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures


    \part{The first}

    \chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

    \chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}

    \chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

    \part{The second}

    \chapter{Another Test Chapter with Figures}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

UPDATE

If I replace the document block of the solution below with this:

```
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures


\part{The first}

\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

\part{The second}

\chapter{Look no figures here either}

\chapter{Another Test Chapter with Figures}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}

\chapter{Another in the same part}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I then get:

[image: LOF snapshot]

which duplicates Part titles even when the chapters are sequential (4 and 5 circled in blue to highlight this) and aren't interspersed with a chapter missing figures.

Comment: You've made a comment but apparently deleted it, something about `grouping`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Yeah, sorry about that.  I was debating whether I would post it as a distinct question or not.  I got an excellent answer more common to the spirit of the original attempts I had made using the code in the linked questions, and started to feel sort of bad about asking to change it, so I deleted it.  I will restate it below in case it's actually a trivial change.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - My grouping question was pointing out that I made a bad example in the MWE.  The block quote is actually more relevant.  If I include 2 chapters with figures in a single part, using your solution below I get a repetition of the common part title above each chapter.  As the quote block above describes it would be best if there was not repetition.

Comment: I am confused. Do you really use my MWE or is there anything in the real document you want to obtain that changes something? I'll add a screenshot about the output of my 'solution'. There is only one part title per chapter group. However, the culprit is, that there is also a part title when chapters without figures are included. That should be changed, in my point of view.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - "There is also a part title when chapters without figures are included".  I am a little surprised at this behaviour, I guess I don't fully understand what is responsible for this. I only have 1 part in my document that has figures, and they are in two sequential chapters.  This problem would make sense if there was a chapter without figures in between to chapters, but I guess it does make a certain amount of sense that any missing chapter would mess up the counters...  I am updating my question above to include the screenshot your solution MWE output gives me.

Comment: Yes, I see now ... it's the toggling, I assume. I'll check

Comment: I've deleted the second version from yesterday and added some new one, with an additional `newpart` toggle, which is toggled false if the `figure` or `table` environment writes the `part` information to `Lof` or `LoT` -- it has no chance to write again, until `newpart` is toggled true (which is done by `\part` command.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\contentsline` stuff is wrongly used in the O.P.'s document, i.e. wrongly placed `{}` delimiters.

For example

```
 \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{part}%
                    {\protect\numberline{\thisparttitle}}{}{3.2em} }
```

tries to write a `\numberline` with the part title as the number, leaving out the title and setting the page number to be `3.2em` which is in fact a length.

One correct way is

```
\addtocontents{lof}{%
\protect\contentsline{part}{
  \protect\numberline{\thispartnumber}\thisparttitle}{% page number group -- empty here 
}% end of \contentsline
}% end of \addtocontents
```

The same holds true for the chapter titles and the `LoT`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % or xpatch

\makeatletter

    % initial definitions of the part info (name and number)
\def\thisparttitle{}\def\thispartnumber{}
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}

\newtoggle{noFigs}
\newtoggle{noTabs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}\global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@part}{\gdef\thisparttitle{#1}\gdef\thispartnumber{\thepart}\global\toggletrue{noFigs}\global\toggletrue{noTabs}}{}{}

% the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
        \iftoggle{noFigs}{%
          \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\protect\numberline{\thispartnumber}\thisparttitle}{}}%
          \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thischapternumber}\thischaptertitle}{}}%
          \global\togglefalse{noFigs}%
        }{}
    }%
    \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
        \iftoggle{noTabs}{%
          \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\protect\numberline{\thispartnumber}\thisparttitle}{}}%
          \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thischapternumber}\thischaptertitle}{}}%
          \global\togglefalse{noTabs}%
        }{}
      }%
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures


\part{The first}

\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

\part{The second}

\chapter{Another Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Now with `hyperref` support, but without showing the page number for chapters and parts. (Please note: due to the toggle style, this won't work if a figure is not in a chapter!) The better way would to ask for the figure number.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter

% initial definitions of the part info (name and number)
\def\thisparttitle{}\def\thispartnumber{}
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}

\newtoggle{noFigs}
\newtoggle{noTabs}
\newtoggle{newpart}


\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
  \xdef\thisparttitle{#1}%    Evaluate the parameter #1
  \global\togglefalse{noFigs}%
  \global\togglefalse{noTabs}%
  \global\toggletrue{newpart}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}


\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}% 
  \xdef\thischaptertitle{#1}%  Evaluate the parameter #1
  \global\togglefalse{noFigs}%
  \global\togglefalse{noTabs}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}
\makeatother



\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \nottoggle{noFigs}{%
      \iftoggle{newpart}{%
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}\thisparttitle}{}{part.\theHpart}}%
      \global\togglefalse{newpart}%
      }{}%
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\thischaptertitle}{}{chapter.\theHchapter}}%
      \global\toggletrue{noFigs}
    }{}
  }

  \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \nottoggle{noTabs}{%
      \iftoggle{newpart}{%
      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}\thisparttitle}{}{part.\theHpart}}%
      \global\togglefalse{newpart}%
      }{}%
      \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\thischaptertitle}{}{chapter.\theHchapter}}%
      \global\toggletrue{noTabs}%
    }{}
  }
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\part{The first}

\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

\part{The second}

\chapter{Look no figures here either}


\chapter{Another Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}

%\chapter{Another chapter, without figures}


\chapter{Another in the same part}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}




\part{Without figs}

\chapter{A chapter with a table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Some table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It appears your solution is incompatible with the `bookmark` and `hyperref` packages.  `cleveref` is fine however.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @EngBIRD: The problem is the `\addtocmd` stuff, which I used unchanged from your example, so the problem is already there. I'll try to change this

Comment: @EngBIRD: See my update please

Comment: Thanks, I still can't compile your code with your solution in the presence of `hyperref` and `bookmark`.  I have updated my MWE's preamble, but not the actual area that your code targets to fix.  Basically it's saying that chapter doesn't match it's definition.

Comment: @EngBIRD: If I use the updated document it fails exactly at `\addtocmd` stuff -- this has nothing to do with my solution.

Comment: If I add  `\usepackage{bookmark}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your current solution, and I may be misinterpreting the error feedback, I don't think it is failing at `\addtocmd`.

Comment: @EngBIRD: I've added `bookmarks` and `hyperref` at the position I intended to in the MWE, especially `hyperref` must be after the `\xpatchcmd`! And of course my solution runs without compilation errors, otherwise I wouldn't have posted it!

Comment: I know your solution works, I can compile your MWE without complication so I am sorry to imply anything other than my own ignorance about your solution.  I missed your insertion of `hyperref` so  I did not realize `hyperref`'s inclusion was location specific as I was trying to merge between your fully functioning MWE and my messy cls file.  I really appreciate the help!  I also missed the exclusion of `etoolbox`, which is now the final complication I will investigate.

Comment: @EngBIRD: The usual rule is: `hyperref` at the end of the preamble, since it does a lot of (sophisticated/weird) things. The `\AtBeginEnvironment` stuff is location specific too, since it requires the 4th and 5th argument to contentsline, which were introduced by `hyperref`

Comment: @EngBIRD: No worries about excluding `etoolbox`. `xpatch` loads it anyway, since `egreg` (the author of `xpatch`) extends `etoolbox` actually

Comment: Wow!  Very impressive and versatile.  Two solutions in one answer.... too bad there is no loop hole for two upvotes.  Thanks for putting so much time into this.  This integrated perfectly and looks great.