# Include Chapters have figures with caption In List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am using the code in [Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc/) to include chapters in the LOF. The problem is that some chapters may have at most one figure but with no caption. How to ignore these chapters?
Blew is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % or xpatch

\makeatletter
% initial definitions of the chapter info (name and number)
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}%
  {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}

% the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, 
% it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \iftoggle{noFigs}{
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
    }{}
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with ‎only ‎one‎ Figure and no caption}
\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Another Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps my second answer (the one at the bottom of my post there) to this question here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253223/add-both-part-and-chapter-titles-to-list-of-figures-with-formatting-and-line-wra) might be a solution for your problem too. The page-numbers can be added again ;-) It has to be changed of course for the non-caption-figure - feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reused the code from my answer to this question [Add both part and chapter titles to list of figures with formatting and line wrapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253223/add-both-part-and-chapter-titles-to-list-of-figures-with-formatting-and-line-wra?lq=1)

and just added a condition if `figure` counter is greater than zero, a `\caption` has been used (most likely). Clearly, this requires a per chapter resetting of the figure counter, which is true in standard classes (and unless not changed with `chngcntr` or `\@remfromreset`)

Note that the chapters without figures or with figures but without caption, they aren't added to the LoF!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter


% initial definitions of the part info (name and number)
\def\thisparttitle{}\def\thispartnumber{}
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}

\newtoggle{noFigs}
\newtoggle{noTabs}
\newtoggle{newpart}



\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
  \xdef\thisparttitle{#1}%    Evaluate the parameter #1
  \global\togglefalse{noFigs}%
  \global\togglefalse{noTabs}%
  \global\toggletrue{newpart}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}


\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}% 
  \xdef\thischaptertitle{#1}%  Evaluate the parameter #1
  \global\togglefalse{noFigs}%
  \global\togglefalse{noTabs}%
}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}
\makeatother




\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{%
    \nottoggle{noFigs}{%
      \ifnumgreater{\value{figure}}{0}{%
      \iftoggle{newpart}{%
        \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}\thisparttitle}{}{part.\theHpart}}%
        \global\togglefalse{newpart}%
      }{}%
        \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\thischaptertitle}{}{chapter.\theHchapter}}%
        \global\toggletrue{noFigs}
       }{}%
    }{}%
  }

  \AfterEndEnvironment{table}{%
    \nottoggle{noTabs}{%
      \ifnumgreater{\value{table}}{0}{%
        \iftoggle{newpart}{%
          \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}\thisparttitle}{}{part.\theHpart}}%
          \global\togglefalse{newpart}%
        }{}%
        \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\thischaptertitle}{}{chapter.\theHchapter}}%
        \global\toggletrue{noTabs}%
      }{}%
    }{}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\part{The first}

\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text Number one}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text Number two}
\end{figure}


\chapter{A chapter with figure, but no caption}
\begin{figure}
% One without figure
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

\part{The second}

\chapter{Look no figures here either}


\chapter{Another Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{caption text from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
% No caption
\end{figure}


\chapter{Another in the same part}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{caption text}
    \end{figure}




\part{Without figs}

\chapter{A chapter with a table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Some table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First chapter in List of Tables have not title! please check.

Comment: @MathMan: Yes, I've forgotten to change `\AtEndEnvironment` to `\AfterEndEnvironment` for the `table` environment. Thanks for notifying me

Comment: Not worked! Mr Hupfer

Comment: @MathMan: Not worked is not very helpful. I can clearly see a chapter title in the list of tables