# Chapters in List of figures with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents

I can't group my list of figures by chapters. I've tried solutions proposed in subjects [Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc) and [Include Chapters have figures with caption In List of Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255678/include-chapters-have-figures-with-caption-in-list-of-figures) but the first solution doesn't work without any compiling error, and the second one makes an error :

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   argument> \thechapitre

This is a MWE :

**Main :**

```
\documentclass{Maclasse}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} % hyperliens PDF
\usepackage{bookmark} % signets PDF
\usepackage{tocloft}

%% List of Equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{listofequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequation}[2]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{equation}{\protect\numberline{\ref{#2}}#1}\par}

\makeatletter
\let\l@equation\l@figure
\makeatother

% List of figures
\makeatletter % Spaces between number and title of figures
 \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter % Separations between chapters in list of figures
\def\thischapitretitle{}
\apptocmd{\@chapitre}{\gdef\thischapitretitle{#1}}{}{}

\newcommand{\DeclareDividedList}[1]%
  {\newcounter{#1@chapitre}\setcounter{#1@chapitre}{0}}

\pretocmd{\addcontentsline}%
  {\ifltxcounter{#1@chapitre}%
   {%
 \ifnumgreater{\thechapitre}{\value{#1@chapitre}}{%
   \setcounter{#1@chapitre}{\thechapitre}%
   \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{chapitre}%
     {\protect\numberline {\thechapitre} {\thischapitretitle}}{}{} }
     }{}%
   }{}%
  }{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareDividedList{lof}
\DeclareDividedList{lot}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoffigures % Table des figures

\chapitre{Ch 1}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\chapitre{Ch 2}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Class :**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Maclasse}[2014/01/30 v0.4 classe pour ma thèse]
\LoadClassWithOptions{memoir} % classe de référence: memoir

%%% OPTIONS %%%

\RequirePackage{kvoptions} % support des options de type clé=valeur
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=drfr,prefix=drfr@}

\DeclareBoolOption[true]{footnotereset}
\DeclareBoolOption[true]{versetitle}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{drfr}

\ifdrfr@footnotereset
% reset des notes de bas de page à chaque nouvelle page
\PassOptionsToPackage{perpage}{footmisc}
\else
% numérotation continue des notes de bas de pages du début à la fin
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\fi

%%% PACKAGES REQUIS %%%
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % pour bonne interprétation des caractère     spéciaux dans la classe
\RequirePackage{ifdraft} % comportements spécifiques quand l'option de     classe draft est présente
\RequirePackage{xifthen} % code conditionnel
\RequirePackage{xstring} % code conditionnel
\RequirePackage{footmisc} % gestion des notes de bas de page
\RequirePackage{engrec} % compteur à symbole grecs
\RequirePackage{filecontents} % génération des fichers de style makeindex
\usepackage{babel} % support des langues
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} % support des guillemets babel

%%% PAGE DE TITRE %%%

% Numéro d'ordre
\newcommand{\numerodordre}[1]{\def\theordrnumber{#1}}

% université
\newcommand{\university}[1]{\def\theuniversity{#1}}

% école doctorante
\newcommand{\school}[1]{\def\theschool{#1}}

% Numéro d'école doctorale
\newcommand{\numeroEDSF}[1]{\def\thedoctschoolnumber{#1}}

% spécialité de la thèse
\newcommand{\speciality}[1]{\def\thespeciality{#1}}

% date de soutenance
\newcommand{\approvaldate}[1]{\def\theapprovaldate{#1}}

% titre
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\def\thetitle{#1}}

% auteur
\renewcommand{\author}[2]{\def\theauthor{#1 \textsc{#2}}}

% Président du jury
% {civilité}{prénom}{nom}{poste}
\newcommand{\president}[4]{%
\def\thepresident{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thepresidentjob{#4}}

% directeur de thèse
% {civilité}{prénom}{nom}{poste}
\newcommand{\director}[4]{%
\def\thedirector{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thedirectorjob{#4}}

% rapporteurs
% {civilité}{prénom}{nom}{poste}
\newcommand{\reportera}[4]{%
\def\thereportera{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thereporterajob{#4}}

\newcommand{\reporterb}[4]{%
\def\thereporterb{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thereporterbjob{#4}}

% autres membres du jury
% {civilité}{prénom}{nom}{poste}
\newcommand{\membera}[4]{%
\def\themembera{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thememberajob{#4}}

\newcommand{\memberb}[4]{%
\def\thememberb{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thememberbjob{#4}}

% page de titre pour la soutenance
\newcommand{\maketitlepage}{{%
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushleft}
{\Large \No d'Ordre : D.U. \theordrnumber}\\[1\onelineskip]
\end{flushleft}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE \textbf{UNIVERSIT\'E \theuniversity} \\}
{\Large U.F.R. Sciences et Technologies \\[1\onelineskip]}
{\LARGE \textbf{\'ECOLE DOCTORALE DES \theschool \\
\No \thedoctschoolnumber} \\[1\onelineskip]}

{ {\LARGE THESE \\[1\onelineskip]}
 pr\'esent\'ee pour obtenir le grade de \\
 \textbf{DOCTEUR D'UNIVERSIT\'E} \\
 \textit{\textbf{Sp\'ecialit\'e : \thespeciality}}  \\[1\onelineskip]
 Par : {\Large \textbf{\theauthor}}\\
 Titulaire du Master Recherche sp\'ecialit\'e Physico-Chimie de l'Atmosph\`ere et du Climat}\\
\rule{0.9\linewidth}{.5pt} \\
{\LARGE\bfseries \thetitle \\ \rule{0.9\linewidth}{.5pt}}
 \\ soutenue publiquement le \theapprovaldate , devant la commission d'examen : \\[1\onelineskip]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Pr\'esident : & \thepresident & \thepresidentjob \\
Rapporteurs: & \thereportera & \thereporterajob \\
  & \thereporterb & \thereporterbjob \\
Examinateurs : & \themembera & \thememberajob \\
  & \thememberb & \thememberbjob \\
Directeur de th\`ese : & \thedirector & \thedirectorjob \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\cleardoublepage
}}

%%% TEXTE %%%

\OnehalfSpacing % espacement de ligne
\frenchbsetup{PartNameFull=false} % "partie I" préféré à "première partie"

%%% EN-TETES / PIEDS DE PAGE %%%

% date de compilation indiquée en mode draft uniquement
\newcommand{\addversion}{\ifdraft{Brouillon datant du \today}{}}

% définition du style des headers et footers
\makepagestyle{corpus}
\makeheadrule{corpus}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
%\makefootrule{corpus}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
\makeevenhead{corpus}{\small\thetitle}{}{\small\addversion}
\makeoddhead{corpus}{}{}{\small\rightmark}
\makeevenfoot{corpus}{}{\small\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{corpus}{}{\small\thepage}{}
\makepsmarks{corpus}{%
\nouppercaseheads
\createmark{part}{right}{shownumber}{Titre }{. \ }
\createmark{chapter}{right}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
\createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{ \ }
\createplainmark{toc}{right}{\contentsname}
\createplainmark{lof}{right}{\listfigurename}
\createplainmark{lot}{right}{\listtablename}
\createplainmark{bib}{right}{\bibname}
\createplainmark{index}{right}{\indexname}
\createplainmark{glossary}{right}{\glossaryname}
}

% hack de la classe memoir: équivalent à \createmark{book}, non disponible
\def\bookpagemark#1{%
  \markright{%
  \ifnum\c@secnumdepth > -2
    \if@mainmatter
      Partie \thebook. \ %
    \fi
  \fi
#1}}

\pagestyle{corpus}


%%% SECTIONS %%%

%% [-2] parties ("Première partie")
%
%% macro de conversion compteur => chaine de caractères de genre féminin
%\newcommand{\counterToFrenchF}[1]{\ifcase\value{#1}\or Première\or
%     Deuxième\or Troisième\or Quatrième\or Cinquième\or
%     Sixième\or Septième\or Huitième\or Neuvième\or Dixième\or
%     Onzième\or Douzième\or Treizième\or Quatorzième\or Quinzième\or
%     Seizième\or Dix-septième\or Dix-huitième\or Dix-neuvième\or     Vingtième\fi}
%\renewcommand*{\bookname}{\protect\counterToFrenchF{book}~partie}
%\renewcommand{\booknamenum}{} % espace entre intitulé et numéro
%\renewcommand{\printbooknum}{} % numéro
%\newcommand{\partie}{\book}
%
%% [-1] titres (I)
%
%\AtBeginDocument{%
%    \renewcommand*{\partname}{Titre}
%}
%\counterwithin*{part}{book}% RAZ du compteur \part dans un nouveau book
%\newcommand{\titre}{\part}

% [0] chapitres (1)

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}% RAZ du compteur \chapter dans une nouvelle     part
\newcommand{\chapitre}{\chapter}

% [1] sections (I)

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
%\setbeforesecskip{}
%\setsecindent{}
\setaftersecskip{2em}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\raggedright}
\setsechook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}

% [2] paragraphes (§1)

\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}.}%\S~
%\setbeforesubsecskip{}
%\setsubsecindent{}
\setaftersubsecskip{1.5em}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\raggedright}
\setsubsechook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\paragraphe}{\subsection}

% [3] sous-paragraphes (A.)

\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection \alph{subsubsection}.}
%\setbeforesubsubsecskip{}
%\setsubsubsecindent{}
%\setaftersubsubsecskip{}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\raggedright}
\setsubsubsechook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\souspara}{\subsubsection}

% [4] alinéas (1.)

\renewcommand*{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsection \arabic{paragraph}.}
%\setbeforeparaskip{}
%\setparaindent{}
\setafterparaskip{1em}
\setparaheadstyle{\bfseries\raggedright}
\setparahook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\alinea}{\paragraph}

% [5] sous-alinéas (a.)

\renewcommand*{\thesubparagraph}{\alph{subparagraph}.}
%\setsubparaindent{0pt}
\setaftersubparaskip{0.5em} % 
\setsubparaheadstyle{\bfseries\raggedright}
\setsubparahook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\sousalinea}{\subparagraph}

% [6] points (i.)

\newcommand{\subsubparagraph}{\@startsection{subsubparagraph}
  {6}{\parindent}{1\baselineskip plus 0.25\baselineskip}
  {.5em}{\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}}
\newlistentry[subparagraph]{subsubparagraph}{toc}{5}
\newcommand*{\subsubparagraphmark}[1]{} % gobble heading mark
\renewcommand{\thesubsubparagraph}{\roman{subsubparagraph}.}
\newcommand{\point}{\subsubparagraph}

% [7] souspoints (alpha.)

\newcommand{\subsubsubparagraph}{\@startsection{subsubsubparagraph}
  {7}{\parindent}{1\baselineskip plus 0.25\baselineskip}
  {.5em}{\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}}
\newlistentry[subsubparagraph]{subsubsubparagraph}{toc}{6}
\newcommand*{\subsubsubparagraphmark}[1]{} % gobble heading mark
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsubparagraph}{\engrec{subsubsubparagraph}.}
\newcommand{\souspoint}{\subsubsubparagraph}

% [8] versets (paragraphes numérotés)

\newcommand{\versetsec}[1]{\@startsection{versetsec}
  {8}{\parindent}{0.5\baselineskip}
  {#1}{\small\textbf}}
\newlistentry{versetsec}{toc}{7}
\newcommand*{\versetsecmark}[1]{} % gobble heading mark
\renewcommand{\theversetsec}{\arabic{versetsec}.}

\newcommand{\versetsecfilled}{\versetsec{-1em}}
\newcommand{\versetsecblank}{\versetsec{-0em}}

% référencement des versets dans l'index
\newcounter{indexv}

% style des versets: caractères séparateur avec le texte
\newcommand{\versetsep}{}
\newcommand{\versetsepifempty}{}
\newcommand{\versetsepspace}{1em}
\newcommand{\versetsepstyle}{\normalfont}

% ajout de point final si nécessaire.
% aucun point n'est ajouté si le verset est déjà fini par "!", "?", "." ou     "/ldots".
\newcommand{\versetdot}[1]{%
  \IfEndWith{#1}{.}{}{%
    \IfEndWith{#1}{?}{}{%
      \IfEndWith{#1}{!}{}{%
        \IfEndWith{#1}{\ldots}{}{.}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\versetcontent}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\versetsecblank{#1}}%
    {\versetsecfilled{#1\protect\versetdot{#1}}}%
    }
}

\newcommand{\verset}[1]{%
  \ifdrfr@versetitle%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
      {\ifthenelse{\equal{\versetsepifempty}{}}%
        {\versetcontent{#1}}%
        {\versetcontent{{\versetsepstyle\versetsepifempty}}}}%
      {\ifthenelse{\equal{\versetsep}{}}%
        {\versetcontent{#1}}%
        {\versetcontent{#1\hspace{\versetsepspace}    {\versetsepstyle\versetsep}}}}%
  \else%
    \versetcontent{{\versetsepstyle\versetsepifempty}}%
  \fi%
  \addtocounter{indexv}{1}% 
}

% numérotation visible
\setsecnumdepth{all}
\maxsecnumdepth{all}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7} % pour points (6) et sous-points (7)

% option pour éviter les pbs d'hyperliens ambigus (de \part et \chapter)
\PassOptionsToPackage{hypertexnames=false}{hyperref}

%%% REFERENCES CROISEES

\AtBeginDocument{%
% autoref est disponible via le package hyperref
\renewcommand*{\bookautorefname}{Partie}
\renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Titre}
\renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapitre}
}


%%% GLOSSAIRE

\renewcommand{\memgloterm}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\memglodesc}[1]{\hspace{1ex}#1}
\renewcommand{\memglonum}[1]{}

%%% INDEX %%%

\renewcommand*{\seename}{\textit{voir}}
\renewcommand*{\alsoname}{\textit{v. aussi}}

\ifdraft{\showindexmarks}{}

% index de base par versets
\newcommand{\indexvfilename}{\jobname}
\newcommand{\makeindexv}{\makeindex[\indexvfilename]}
\newcommand{\indexv}[1]{\specialindex{\indexvfilename}{indexv}{#1}}
\newcommand{\printindexv}{\printindex[\indexvfilename]}

% index d'auteur par versets
\newcommand{\indexafilename}{auteurs}
\newcommand{\makeindexa}{\makeindex[\indexafilename]}
\newcommand{\indexa}[1]{\specialindex{\indexafilename}{indexv}{#1}}
\newcommand{\printindexa}{\printindex[\indexafilename]}

% entête de l'index
\newcommand{\idxmark}[1]{#1\markboth{#1}{#1}}

% raccourcis de style pour entrées indexées
\newcommand{\hyperbf}[1]{\textbf{\hyperpage{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hyperit}[1]{\textit{\hyperpage{#1}}}


%%% SOMMAIRE & TABLE DES MATIERES %%%

% paramètres communs
\renewcommand{\cftbookname}{Partie\space}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartname}{Titre\space}%
%
\cftsetindents{subsubparagraph}{4em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsubparagraph}{5em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{versetsec}{6em}{2em}

% sommaire
\newcommand*{\setupshorttoc}{%
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Sommaire}
\let\oldchangetocdepth\changetocdepth
\renewcommand*{\changetocdepth}[1]{}
\let\oldcftchapterfillnum\cftchapterfillnum
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}% Parties / Titres / Chapitres / Sections / Paragraphes / Sous-paragraphes seulement
% A modifier dans sommaire.tex
%
%\cftpagenumbersoff{book}
%\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
%\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
%
\renewcommand{\tocheadstart}{}
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforebookskip}{1em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftbookfont}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookindent}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookpagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries\large}%
%\renewcommand{\cftafterbookskip}{}%
%\renewcommand{\cftbookleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforepartskip}{0.5em}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\scshape}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartindent}{0.5em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalfont\scshape}%
    %\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}%
\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapitre\space}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterindent}{1em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftchapternumwidth}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}%
%\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
}%

\newcommand{\shorttableofcontents}{%
\clearpage
\setupshorttoc
\tableofcontents
}%

% table des matières
\newcommand*{\setuplongtoc}{%
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table des matières}%
\let\changetocdepth\oldchangetocdepth
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}%
%
% \cftpagenumberson{book}
% \cftpagenumberson{part}
% \cftpagenumberson{chapter}
%
\renewcommand{\tocheadstart}{\chapterheadstart}
%
\renewcommand{\cftbookbreak}{\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}\clearpage}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforebookskip}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookindent}{1em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftbooknumwidth}{}%
%\renewcommand{\cftafterbookskip}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforepartskip}{1.5em}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\large}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartindent}{0em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\large}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterindent}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapitre\space}%
%\renewcommand{\cftchapternumwidth}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesectionskip}{0.5em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\normalfont\large}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsectionname}{Section\space}%
\renewcommand{\cftsectionindent}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsectionnumwidth}{5.5em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsectionskip}{0.5em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfont}{\normalfont\scshape}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionname}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionindent}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionnumwidth}{2em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
%\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsubsectionskip}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\normalfont\itshape}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionname}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionindent}{1em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth}{2em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
%\renewcommand{\cftbeforeparagraphskip}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftparagraphfont}{\normalfont}%
%\renewcommand{\cftparagraphname}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftparagraphindent}{2em}%
\renewcommand{\cftparagraphnumwidth}{2em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftparagraphleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
%\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubparagraphskip}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphfont}{\normalfont}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphname}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphindent}{3em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphnumwidth}{2em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubparagraphfont}{\normalfont\small}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsubparagraphfont}{\normalfont\small}%
%
}%

\newcommand{\longtableofcontents}{%
\clearpage
\setuplongtoc
\tableofcontents
}%

% génération du fichier de style .ist
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ist}
% output main entry <entry> as: \item \idxmark{<entry>}, 
item_0 "\n\\item \\idxmark{"
delim_0 "}, "
% not forgetting the subitem case%    added 2008
item_x1 "} \n \\subitem "
% Wrap and uppercase head letters
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
\end{filecontents}

% génération du fichier de style .gst
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.gst}
% Output style parameters
preamble "\\begin{theglossary}"
postamble "\n\\end{theglossary}\n"
item_0 "\n\\glossitem"
delim_0 "{\\memglonum{"
encap_suffix "}}}"
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
% Input style parameters
keyword "\\glossaryentry"
\end{filecontents}

\endinput
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You state that *chapitre* is the only difference to the original `memoir` class, but this is exactly the breaking point seen in the error message. Why change a running system? You quite likely broke something, and we cannot see it, because it is in your own class.

Comment: `memoir` provides the functionality of `tocloft`, you don't have to use the package, but rather read the `memoir`documentation for details.

Comment: Thank your for your fast answer. It's not the only difference but the others are not for this point (bibliography, etc.). The class is modified for a french scientific version of phd. I had to add tocloft because List of Equations didn't work without this package

Comment: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=94778#p94778

Comment: @Alex: I am the author of the second answer you linked. I want to help,but not without seeing the real class. Apparently, there is no `chapitre` counter defined!

Comment: @Johannes_B : I haven't any problem with that. I want to have separation between chapters in List of figures.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : I have edited my first post with the add of class.

Comment: @Alex: Your class has errors.

Comment: There's no `chapitre` counter, wrong `}` and no `\l@chapitre` command.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : There is my complete class.

Comment: @Alex: Why did you not post it right from the start? :-(

Comment: Sorry I wanted to post a MWE but I have suppressed too many things. I've not too experience of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with: I cite Boromir in 'The Fellowship of the Ring': There's evil in that class that does not sleep ;-)

Correcting many errors....

- `\usepackage` → `\RequirePackage`
- unpaired `}` at line 306
- `\newcommand{\chapitre}{\chapter}` does **not** make `\chapitre` behave like `\chapter`, especially, there's no `\l@chapitre` command, nor is there a counter named `chapitre` then, nor is `\@chapitre` ever defined -- the patching with `\addtocmd` works, because it does not check if `\@chapitre` is ever defined.

The whole issue is actually shooting oneself into the foot. Why not keeping `\chapter` as it is defined -- all causes more trouble than necessary.

The `\thechapitre` counter formater is also not defined and must be `\let\thechapitre\thechapter` to be effective. Since `chapitre` is never stepped, it must be made an alias counter of `chapter`, i.e.

```
\let\c@chapitre\c@chapter
```

Also don't use `\setcounter{foo}{\theotherfoo}`, since `\theotherfoo` is very likely no number!!! Use `\setcounter{foo}{\value{otherfoo}` for this.

---

```
\documentclass[french]{MaclasseNouveau}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} % hyperliens PDF
\usepackage{bookmark} % signets PDF
\usepackage{tocloft}

%% List of Equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{listofequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequation}[2]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{equation}{\protect\numberline{\ref{#2}}#1}\par}

\makeatletter
\let\l@equation\l@figure
\makeatother

% List of figures
\makeatletter % Spaces between number and title of figures
 \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter % Separations between chapters in list of figures
\def\thischapitretitle{}

%\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\protect\gdef\thischapitretitle{#1}}{\typeout{Foo}}{}
\LetLtxMacro\memoir@@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    \gdef\thischapitretitle{#2}%
   }{%
     \gdef\thischapitretitle{#1}%
   }%
   \memoir@@chapter[#1]{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\DeclareDividedList}[1]{%
  \newcounter{#1@chapitre}
  %\setcounter{#1@chapitre}{0}% Not necessary
}

\pretocmd{\addcontentsline}%
{\ifltxcounter{#1@chapitre}%
  {%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{chapitre}}{\value{#1@chapitre}}{%
      \setcounter{#1@chapitre}{\value{chapitre}}%
      \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{chapitre}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thechapitre} {\thischapitretitle}}{}{} }
    }{}%
  }{}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareDividedList{lof}
\DeclareDividedList{lot}

%\listfiles

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoffigures % Table des figures
\mainmatter
\chapitre{Ch 1}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\chapitre{Ch 2}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**MaclasseNouveau.cls**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MaclasseNouveau}[2014/01/30 v0.4 classe pour ma thèse]
\LoadClassWithOptions{memoir} % classe de référence: memoir

%%% OPTIONS %%%

\RequirePackage{kvoptions} % support des options de type clé=valeur
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=drfr,prefix=drfr@}

\DeclareBoolOption[true]{footnotereset}
\DeclareBoolOption[true]{versetitle}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{drfr}

\ifdrfr@footnotereset
% reset des notes de bas de page à chaque nouvelle page
\PassOptionsToPackage{perpage}{footmisc}
\else
% numérotation continue des notes de bas de pages du début à la fin
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\fi

%%% PACKAGES REQUIS %%%
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % pour bonne interprétation des caractère     spéciaux dans la classe
\RequirePackage{ifdraft} % comportements spécifiques quand l'option de     classe draft est présente
\RequirePackage{xifthen} % code conditionnel
\RequirePackage{xstring} % code conditionnel
\RequirePackage{footmisc} % gestion des notes de bas de page
\RequirePackage{engrec} % compteur à symbole grecs
\RequirePackage{filecontents} % génération des fichers de style makeindex
\RequirePackage{babel} % support des langues
\RequirePackage[babel]{csquotes} % support des guillemets babel
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro}

%%% PAGE DE TITRE %%%

% Numéro d'ordre
\newcommand{\numerodordre}[1]{\def\theordrnumber{#1}}

% université
\newcommand{\university}[1]{\def\theuniversity{#1}}

% école doctorante
\newcommand{\school}[1]{\def\theschool{#1}}

% Numéro d'école doctorale
\newcommand{\numeroEDSF}[1]{\def\thedoctschoolnumber{#1}}

% spécialité de la thèse
\newcommand{\speciality}[1]{\def\thespeciality{#1}}

% date de soutenance
\newcommand{\approvaldate}[1]{\def\theapprovaldate{#1}}

% titre
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\def\thetitle{#1}}

% auteur
\renewcommand{\author}[2]{\def\theauthor{#1 \textsc{#2}}}

% Président du jury
% {civilité}{prénom}{nom}{poste}
\newcommand{\president}[4]{%
\def\thepresident{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thepresidentjob{#4}}

% directeur de thèse
% {civilité}{prénom}{nom}{poste}
\newcommand{\director}[4]{%
\def\thedirector{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thedirectorjob{#4}}

% rapporteurs
% {civilité}{prénom}{nom}{poste}
\newcommand{\reportera}[4]{%
\def\thereportera{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thereporterajob{#4}}

\newcommand{\reporterb}[4]{%
\def\thereporterb{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thereporterbjob{#4}}

% autres membres du jury
% {civilité}{prénom}{nom}{poste}
\newcommand{\membera}[4]{%
\def\themembera{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thememberajob{#4}}

\newcommand{\memberb}[4]{%
\def\thememberb{\textbf{#1 #2 \textsc{#3}}}
\def\thememberbjob{#4}}

% page de titre pour la soutenance
\newcommand{\maketitlepage}{{%
\thispagestyle{empty}


\begin{flushleft}
{\Large \No d'Ordre : D.U. \theordrnumber}\\[1\onelineskip]
\end{flushleft}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE \textbf{UNIVERSIT\'E \theuniversity} \\}
{\Large U.F.R. Sciences et Technologies \\[1\onelineskip]}
{\LARGE \textbf{\'ECOLE DOCTORALE DES \theschool \\
\No \thedoctschoolnumber} \\[1\onelineskip]}

{ {\LARGE THESE \\[1\onelineskip]}
 pr\'esent\'ee pour obtenir le grade de \\
 \textbf{DOCTEUR D'UNIVERSIT\'E} \\
 \textit{\textbf{Sp\'ecialit\'e : \thespeciality}}  \\[1\onelineskip]
 Par : {\Large \textbf{\theauthor}}\\
 Titulaire du Master Recherche sp\'ecialit\'e Physico-Chimie de l'Atmosph\`ere et du Climat}\\
\rule{0.9\linewidth}{.5pt} \\
{\LARGE\bfseries \thetitle \\ \rule{0.9\linewidth}{.5pt}}
 \\ soutenue publiquement le \theapprovaldate , devant la commission d'examen : \\[1\onelineskip]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Pr\'esident : & \thepresident & \thepresidentjob \\
Rapporteurs: & \thereportera & \thereporterajob \\
  & \thereporterb & \thereporterbjob \\
Examinateurs : & \themembera & \thememberajob \\
  & \thememberb & \thememberbjob \\
Directeur de th\`ese : & \thedirector & \thedirectorjob \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\cleardoublepage
}}
%%% TEXTE %%%

\OnehalfSpacing % espacement de ligne
\frenchbsetup{PartNameFull=false} % "partie I" préféré à "première partie"

%%% EN-TETES / PIEDS DE PAGE %%%

% date de compilation indiquée en mode draft uniquement
\newcommand{\addversion}{\ifdraft{Brouillon datant du \today}{}}

% définition du style des headers et footers
\makepagestyle{corpus}
\makeheadrule{corpus}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
%\makefootrule{corpus}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
\makeevenhead{corpus}{\small\thetitle}{}{\small\addversion}
\makeoddhead{corpus}{}{}{\small\rightmark}
\makeevenfoot{corpus}{}{\small\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{corpus}{}{\small\thepage}{}
\makepsmarks{corpus}{%
\nouppercaseheads
\createmark{part}{right}{shownumber}{Titre }{. \ }
\createmark{chapter}{right}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
\createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{ \ }
\createplainmark{toc}{right}{\contentsname}
\createplainmark{lof}{right}{\listfigurename}
\createplainmark{lot}{right}{\listtablename}
\createplainmark{bib}{right}{\bibname}
\createplainmark{index}{right}{\indexname}
\createplainmark{glossary}{right}{\glossaryname}
}

% hack de la classe memoir: équivalent à \createmark{book}, non disponible
\def\bookpagemark#1{%
  \markright{%
  \ifnum\c@secnumdepth > -2
    \if@mainmatter
      Partie \thebook. \ %
    \fi
  \fi
#1}}

\pagestyle{corpus}

%%% SECTIONS %%%

%% [-2] parties ("Première partie")
%
%% macro de conversion compteur => chaine de caractères de genre féminin
%\newcommand{\counterToFrenchF}[1]{\ifcase\value{#1}\or Première\or
%     Deuxième\or Troisième\or Quatrième\or Cinquième\or
%     Sixième\or Septième\or Huitième\or Neuvième\or Dixième\or
%     Onzième\or Douzième\or Treizième\or Quatorzième\or Quinzième\or
%     Seizième\or Dix-septième\or Dix-huitième\or Dix-neuvième\or     Vingtième\fi}
%\renewcommand*{\bookname}{\protect\counterToFrenchF{book}~partie}
%\renewcommand{\booknamenum}{} % espace entre intitulé et numéro
%\renewcommand{\printbooknum}{} % numéro
%\newcommand{\partie}{\book}
%
%% [-1] titres (I)
%
%\AtBeginDocument{%
%    \renewcommand*{\partname}{Titre}
%}
%\counterwithin*{part}{book}% RAZ du compteur \part dans un nouveau book
%\newcommand{\titre}{\part}

% [0] chapitres (1)

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}% RAZ du compteur \chapter dans une nouvelle     part

%%%% This is no really good idea
\newcommand{\chapitre}{\chapter}  
\newcounter{chapitre}
\let\c@chapitre\c@chapter% Alias counter 
\let\l@chapitre\l@chapter
\let\@chapitre\@chapter
\let\thechapitre\thechapter

% [1] sections (I)

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
%\setbeforesecskip{}
%\setsecindent{}
\setaftersecskip{2em}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\raggedright}
\setsechook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}

% [2] paragraphes (§1)

\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}.}%\S~
%\setbeforesubsecskip{}
%\setsubsecindent{}
\setaftersubsecskip{1.5em}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\raggedright}
\setsubsechook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\paragraphe}{\subsection}

% [3] sous-paragraphes (A.)

\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection \alph{subsubsection}.}
%\setbeforesubsubsecskip{}
%\setsubsubsecindent{}
%\setaftersubsubsecskip{}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\raggedright}
\setsubsubsechook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\souspara}{\subsubsection}

% [4] alinéas (1.)

\renewcommand*{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsection \arabic{paragraph}.}
%\setbeforeparaskip{}
%\setparaindent{}
\setafterparaskip{1em}
\setparaheadstyle{\bfseries\raggedright}
\setparahook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\alinea}{\paragraph}

% [5] sous-alinéas (a.)

\renewcommand*{\thesubparagraph}{\alph{subparagraph}.}
%\setsubparaindent{0pt}
\setaftersubparaskip{0.5em} % 
\setsubparaheadstyle{\bfseries\raggedright}
\setsubparahook{\needspace{4\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\sousalinea}{\subparagraph}

% [6] points (i.)

\newcommand{\subsubparagraph}{\@startsection{subsubparagraph}
  {6}{\parindent}{1\baselineskip plus 0.25\baselineskip}
  {.5em}{\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}}
\newlistentry[subparagraph]{subsubparagraph}{toc}{5}
\newcommand*{\subsubparagraphmark}[1]{} % gobble heading mark
\renewcommand{\thesubsubparagraph}{\roman{subsubparagraph}.}
\newcommand{\point}{\subsubparagraph}

% [7] souspoints (alpha.)

\newcommand{\subsubsubparagraph}{\@startsection{subsubsubparagraph}
  {7}{\parindent}{1\baselineskip plus 0.25\baselineskip}
  {.5em}{\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}}
\newlistentry[subsubparagraph]{subsubsubparagraph}{toc}{6}
\newcommand*{\subsubsubparagraphmark}[1]{} % gobble heading mark
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsubparagraph}{\engrec{subsubsubparagraph}.}
\newcommand{\souspoint}{\subsubsubparagraph}

% [8] versets (paragraphes numérotés)

\newcommand{\versetsec}[1]{\@startsection{versetsec}
  {8}{\parindent}{0.5\baselineskip}
  {#1}{\small\textbf}}
\newlistentry{versetsec}{toc}{7}
\newcommand*{\versetsecmark}[1]{} % gobble heading mark
\renewcommand{\theversetsec}{\arabic{versetsec}.}

\newcommand{\versetsecfilled}{\versetsec{-1em}}
\newcommand{\versetsecblank}{\versetsec{-0em}}

% référencement des versets dans l'index
\newcounter{indexv}

% style des versets: caractères séparateur avec le texte
\newcommand{\versetsep}{}
\newcommand{\versetsepifempty}{}
\newcommand{\versetsepspace}{1em}
\newcommand{\versetsepstyle}{\normalfont}

% ajout de point final si nécessaire.
% aucun point n'est ajouté si le verset est déjà fini par "!", "?", "." ou     "/ldots".
\newcommand{\versetdot}[1]{%
  \IfEndWith{#1}{.}{}{%
    \IfEndWith{#1}{?}{}{%
      \IfEndWith{#1}{!}{}{%
        \IfEndWith{#1}{\ldots}{}{.}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\versetcontent}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
  {\versetsecblank{#1}}%
  {\versetsecfilled{#1\protect\versetdot{#1}}}%
}
%}  WRONG!!!!

\newcommand{\verset}[1]{%
  \ifdrfr@versetitle%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
      {\ifthenelse{\equal{\versetsepifempty}{}}%
        {\versetcontent{#1}}%
        {\versetcontent{{\versetsepstyle\versetsepifempty}}}}%
      {\ifthenelse{\equal{\versetsep}{}}%
        {\versetcontent{#1}}%
        {\versetcontent{#1\hspace{\versetsepspace}    {\versetsepstyle\versetsep}}}}%
  \else%
    \versetcontent{{\versetsepstyle\versetsepifempty}}%
  \fi%
  \addtocounter{indexv}{1}% 
}

% numérotation visible
\setsecnumdepth{all}
\maxsecnumdepth{all}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7} % pour points (6) et sous-points (7)

% option pour éviter les pbs d'hyperliens ambigus (de \part et \chapter)
\PassOptionsToPackage{hypertexnames=false}{hyperref}

%%% REFERENCES CROISEES


\AtBeginDocument{%
% autoref est disponible via le package hyperref
\renewcommand*{\bookautorefname}{Partie}
\renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Titre}
\renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapitre}
}




%%% GLOSSAIRE

\renewcommand{\memgloterm}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\memglodesc}[1]{\hspace{1ex}#1}
\renewcommand{\memglonum}[1]{}

%%% INDEX %%%

\renewcommand*{\seename}{\textit{voir}}
\renewcommand*{\alsoname}{\textit{v. aussi}}

\ifdraft{\showindexmarks}{}

% index de base par versets
\newcommand{\indexvfilename}{\jobname}
\newcommand{\makeindexv}{\makeindex[\indexvfilename]}
\newcommand{\indexv}[1]{\specialindex{\indexvfilename}{indexv}{#1}}
\newcommand{\printindexv}{\printindex[\indexvfilename]}

% index d'auteur par versets
\newcommand{\indexafilename}{auteurs}
\newcommand{\makeindexa}{\makeindex[\indexafilename]}
\newcommand{\indexa}[1]{\specialindex{\indexafilename}{indexv}{#1}}
\newcommand{\printindexa}{\printindex[\indexafilename]}

% entête de l'index
\newcommand{\idxmark}[1]{#1\markboth{#1}{#1}}

% raccourcis de style pour entrées indexées
\newcommand{\hyperbf}[1]{\textbf{\hyperpage{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hyperit}[1]{\textit{\hyperpage{#1}}}


%%% SOMMAIRE & TABLE DES MATIERES %%%

% paramètres communs
\renewcommand{\cftbookname}{Partie\space}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartname}{Titre\space}%
%
\cftsetindents{subsubparagraph}{4em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsubparagraph}{5em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{versetsec}{6em}{2em}

% sommaire
\newcommand*{\setupshorttoc}{%
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Sommaire}
\let\oldchangetocdepth\changetocdepth
\renewcommand*{\changetocdepth}[1]{}
\let\oldcftchapterfillnum\cftchapterfillnum
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}% Parties / Titres / Chapitres / Sections / Paragraphes / Sous-paragraphes seulement
% A modifier dans sommaire.tex
%
%\cftpagenumbersoff{book}
%\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
%\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
%
\renewcommand{\tocheadstart}{}
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforebookskip}{1em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftbookfont}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookindent}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookpagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries\large}%
%\renewcommand{\cftafterbookskip}{}%
%\renewcommand{\cftbookleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforepartskip}{0.5em}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\scshape}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartindent}{0.5em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalfont\scshape}%
    %\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}%
\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapitre\space}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterindent}{1em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftchapternumwidth}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}%
%\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
}%

\newcommand{\shorttableofcontents}{%
\clearpage
\setupshorttoc
\tableofcontents
}%

% table des matières
\newcommand*{\setuplongtoc}{%
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table des matières}%
\let\changetocdepth\oldchangetocdepth
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}%
%
% \cftpagenumberson{book}
% \cftpagenumberson{part}
% \cftpagenumberson{chapter}
%
\renewcommand{\tocheadstart}{\chapterheadstart}
%
\renewcommand{\cftbookbreak}{\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}\clearpage}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforebookskip}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookindent}{1em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftbooknumwidth}{}%
%\renewcommand{\cftafterbookskip}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftbookleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforepartskip}{1.5em}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\large}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartindent}{0em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\large}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterindent}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapitre\space}%
%\renewcommand{\cftchapternumwidth}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesectionskip}{0.5em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\normalfont\large}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsectionname}{Section\space}%
\renewcommand{\cftsectionindent}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsectionnumwidth}{5.5em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsectionskip}{0.5em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfont}{\normalfont\scshape}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionname}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionindent}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionnumwidth}{2em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
%\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsubsectionskip}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\normalfont\itshape}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionname}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionindent}{1em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth}{2em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
%\renewcommand{\cftbeforeparagraphskip}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftparagraphfont}{\normalfont}%
%\renewcommand{\cftparagraphname}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftparagraphindent}{2em}%
\renewcommand{\cftparagraphnumwidth}{2em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftparagraphleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
%\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubparagraphskip}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphfont}{\normalfont}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphname}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphindent}{3em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphnumwidth}{2em}%
%\renewcommand{\cftsubparagraphleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubparagraphfont}{\normalfont\small}%
%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsubparagraphfont}{\normalfont\small}%
%
}%

\newcommand{\longtableofcontents}{%
\clearpage
\setuplongtoc
\tableofcontents
}%

% génération du fichier de style .ist
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ist}
% output main entry <entry> as: \item \idxmark{<entry>}, 
item_0 "\n\\item \\idxmark{"
delim_0 "}, "
% not forgetting the subitem case%    added 2008
item_x1 "} \n \\subitem "
% Wrap and uppercase head letters
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
\end{filecontents}

% génération du fichier de style .gst
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.gst}
% Output style parameters
preamble "\\begin{theglossary}"
postamble "\n\\end{theglossary}\n"
item_0 "\n\\glossitem"
delim_0 "{\\memglonum{"
encap_suffix "}}}"
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
% Input style parameters
keyword "\\glossaryentry"
\end{filecontents}

\endinput
```

Comment: Wiouldn't it be better to put all the other formatting stuff from the preamble to the class file?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Of course, but even better: Don't use such acrobatics at all ;-)

Comment: Every good class should have a `\chapitre` command. MDT template currectly defines *chapter* in 17 different languages.

Comment: @Johannes_B: MDT is a good class? ;-)

Comment: Of course not. lalala

Comment: @Alex: Any news here?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have any time. I will give news as soon as possible

Comment: I won't forget you, but I haven't any time now ! Sorry, I will come back soon

Comment: Hi, I've just copy/paste your MWE in order to check if everything is ok with my real content, and not. I've two problems now :
1) for 1 fig not especially different than others, in the corpus of one chapter, I have the error : "Too many unprocessed float". This figure and the others are in environment `begin{figure}[h]\centered...\end{figure}`

Comment: 2) When I want to have specific margins, I have this error : "Class memoir Error: \paperheight (845.04684pt) and/or \trimtop (0.0pt) are too large for \stockheight (794.96999pt) by 50.07686pt". I want to put this margins :
`\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*}
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout`

Comment: @Alex: I don't get these warnings about the floats. And the other warnings come from the underlying `memoir` class -- things, I have not touched!

Comment: Ok, I will check these errors... Thanks for your answer, I will study it preciously

Comment: I still not have these errors. I don't know why, but it works perfectly. Thanks