# Separate List of Figures and List of Tables by chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to separate the List of Figures and the List of Tables by chapter. I've tried different codes (e.g. [Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc) and [Include Chapters have figures with caption In List of Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255678/include-chapters-have-figures-with-caption-in-list-of-figures)), but finally ended up with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\thechaptername}{}
\newcounter{chapter@last}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]
            {
              \markboth{#1}{}
              \renewcommand{\thechaptername}{#1}
            }

\pretocmd{\caption}
 {\ifnumequal
  {\value{chapter}}
  {\value{chapter@last}}
  {}
  {
   \addtocontents{lot}
    {\protect\numberline{\bfseries\thechapter\quad\thechaptername}}
   \addtocontents{lof}
    {\protect\numberline{\bfseries\thechapter\quad\thechaptername}}
   \setcounter{chapter@last}{\value{chapter}}
  }
  }
  {}
  {}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures and Tables}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test figure 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{test table 1}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test figure 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{test table 2}
\end{table}

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures only}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test figure 3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test figure 4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test figure 5}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Tables only}
\begin{table}
\caption{test table 3}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{test table 4}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{test table 5}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the code produces the chapter titles of chapters that have no figures or tables in it, as can be seen in the examples below:

[image: List of Figures]
[image: List of Tables]

Could someone help solve this issue, so the code produces only the chapter titles of the chapters with figures or tables in it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Fragments of code are not useful.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've edited the question showing the entire code now.

Comment: [There](https://komascript.de/comment/5070#comment-5070) you can find an example (in German) how to do so using `scrreprt` instead of `report`.

Comment: Thanks, but the solution below worked very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep track of the last `figure` or `table` separately. So, instead of just using a `chapter@last` counter, use something like `chapter@last@<type>` for each float type:

```
\newcounter{chapter@last@figure}
\newcounter{chapter@last@table}
```

With this, you can update your prependage to `\caption` as follows:

```
\pretocmd{\caption}{
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@captype}{figure}=0
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=\value{chapter@last@figure}\else
      \addtocontents{lof}
        {\protect\numberline{\bfseries\thechapter\quad\thechaptername}}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@captype}{table}=0
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=\value{chapter@last@table}\else
      \addtocontents{lot}
        {\protect\numberline{\bfseries\thechapter\quad\thechaptername}}%
    \fi
  \fi  
  \expandafter\setcounter\expandafter{chapter@last@\@captype}{\value{chapter}}%
}{}{}
```

The above conditions on whether `\caption` is called within a `figure` or a `table`. If these are the only two types of floats in your document, one could probably simplify it a little.

The update of each `chapter@last@<type>` counter is done automatically at the end of the code based on the `\@captype`.

[image]