# How to include chapters in list of fixmes using KOMA-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, koma-script, fixme

How can I add the chapter to the `\listoffixmes` (`lox`-list) from the `{fixme}`-Package?
I found a lot of solutions for adding the chapter/section to the list of figures / tables / ... but non of them worked (for me) with KOMA-classes.

I think it is no big deal to rebuild a working solution to work with fixme.

**Not working KOMA-Class 'Solutions':**

This solution [Todonotes: group list-of-todos by section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174186/todonotes-group-list-of-todos-by-section)
breaks the `\paragraph{}`-Command and I get the Error: `Latex Error: ./miniExample.tex:425 Missing number, treated as zero.`

[Part title in list of figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103926/part-title-in-list-of-figures-and-tables?lq=1) has two solutions, Solution 1 Works find but also adds Chapters even when there is no element of that list.

The second Solution by Gonzalo Medina doesn't work at all. But I think this is the right way I have to go ...

**Not KOMA-Class 'Solutions':**

[Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc?lq=1)
doesn't work with KOMA-classes (`Latex Error: ./miniExample.tex:376 Missing \endcsname inserted.`)

**A Minimal Example:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


% Code to add the chapter to the listoffixmes ...


\begin{document}

\listoffixmes

\chapter{chapter}
\section{section1}
  \fixme{test1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\section{section2}
\chapter{chapter2}
\section{section3}
  \fixme{test2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which features of the KOMA classes do you really use that enforces you to use them?

Comment: If it is no big deal, why haven't you done it? And if you haven't done it, why do you think it is no big deal?

Comment: You could ask the author of KOMA-script to provide a hack for `scrhack` at http://komascript.de/

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I use scrPageStyles (and a rather big package heading for my Master Thesis) and if i change srcbook to book i get a bunch of error messages. Until this moment I never had problems with KOMA-Classes, so if there is an other way I would like to keep KOMA-Classes.

Comment: @cfr: sry I was not clear in that point: If I find a solution that works with KOMA-Classes I think it's no big deal to rebuild it from Figure/Table/... to work with Fixme. But I haven't found any working soltution for KOMA-Classes so far, which does not break other stuff like \paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the chapters to the List of Corrections you can use

```
\KOMAoptions{chapteratlists=entry}
\addtotoclist[fixme.sty]{lox}
\setuptoc{lox}{chapteratlist}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\listoffixmes}{\listoftoc[{\@fxlistfixmename}]{lox}}
\makeatother
```

Result:

[image]

To remove the chapter entries without fixmes you can use [this solution of Markus Kohm](http://www.komascript.de/comment/5070#comment-5070) (German):

```
% --- Source: http://www.komascript.de/comment/5070#comment-5070 (Markus Kohm)
\makeatletter
\let\chapterhas@original@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\chapterhas{\thechapter}{#1}}%
  \chapterhas@original@addcontentsline{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterhas}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{chapterhas@#1@#2}{true}%
}
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}%
  \if@chaptertolists
    \doforeachtocfile{%
      \iftocfeature{\@currext}{chapteratlist}{%
        \ifundefinedorrelax{chapterhas@\thechapter @\@currext}{%
        }{%
          \addxcontentsline{\@currext}{chapteratlist}[{#1}]{#2}%
        }%
      }{}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{float@addtolists}{}{\scr@float@addtolists@warning}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
% ----
```

This works for all lists controlled by the KOMA-Script package `tocbasic` with chapter entries in the list.

Note that if you are using `hyperref` this code must be inserted after package `hyperref` is loaded. (See the comment of @Kugelfisch15 below this answer.)

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}

\KOMAoptions{chapteratlists=entry}
\addtotoclist[fixme.sty]{lox}
\setuptoc{lox}{chapteratlist}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\listoffixmes}{\listoftoc[{\@fxlistfixmename}]{lox}}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{hyperref}
% --- Source: http://www.komascript.de/comment/5070#comment-5070 (Markus Kohm)
\makeatletter
\let\chapterhas@original@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\chapterhas{\thechapter}{#1}}%
  \chapterhas@original@addcontentsline{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterhas}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{chapterhas@#1@#2}{true}%
}
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}%
  \if@chaptertolists
    \doforeachtocfile{%
      \iftocfeature{\@currext}{chapteratlist}{%
        \ifundefinedorrelax{chapterhas@\thechapter @\@currext}{%
        }{%
          \addxcontentsline{\@currext}{chapteratlist}[{#1}]{#2}%
        }%
      }{}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{float@addtolists}{}{\scr@float@addtolists@warning}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
% ----

\begin{document}
\listoffixmes

\chapter{Chapter with Fixme}
\section{section1}
\fxfatal{test1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\section{section2}

\chapter{Chapter without Fixme}

\chapter{Chapter with Fixme}
\section{section3}
  \fxfatal{test2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you think a `fixme.hak` is in order?

Comment: Thanke you a lot! It works perfect. Note to the code: I have to insert this code after `\usepackage{hyperref}`. If I load `hyperref` after this code the chapters disappear from the ListOfFixmes.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am not sure. I think there are also a number of other packages which define their own list too ...

Answer (score 1):

You could hack `\chapterformat` to add it, although I don't know what side-effects this might have.

Note that `\fixme` is deprecated and the package tells you this when you try to use it. Also, KOMA Script is not at all happy about one of the packages - presumably `fixme`. See the console output for information and recommendations.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\chapterformat}{%
  \addtocontents{lox}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\chaptername{} \thechapter}{}}%
}{\typeout{chapterformat patched OK!}}{\typeout{chapterformat patch failed}}
\begin{document}
\listoffixmes
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section1}
\fxfatal{test1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\section{section2}
\chapter{chapter2}
\section{section3}
\fxfatal{test2}
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter format]

Comment: This solution does also add Chapters without any \fixme entries. like the solution from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103926/part-title-in-list-of-figures-and-tables?lq=1 does.