# Add some text to the List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, text

[image]

So i want to add some text in table of figure as shown in figure.
(i want to add the words encircled by red )

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103928/124842

Comment: this is to include chapter, i need to include part

Comment: @Jdoe: The linked question and its answers are about adding `part` to the `List Of Figures`.

Comment: OTOH, it only applies to KOMA.  As usual a full MWE would have helped.