# Part titles to list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I'm writing my Ph.D. manuscript, and I would like to add subtitles to the list of figures for each part of the document.

I am using `\listoffigures` and no specific package such as tof at the moment, and the result is this:

[image]

It is exactly how I desire (number of the chapter and then of the figure), but I would like to add subtitles indicating "Part I", "Part II", etc., otherwise some figures have the same number without any indication of the part they belong to.

I tried to use `\counterwithin{figure}{part}`, but I didn't like the aesthetics (something like I1, I2, ... II1, II2, ...).
Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103926/277964 and note that the answer would depend on information you've not added to your question, e.g., the used class and maybe on used packages like `titlesec` or `tocloft`. Currently it is also not clear, why the numbers of the figures are repeated. So you should at least add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), of what you've already tried.

Comment: There is no "tof" package (that I'm aware of)... Do you **not** like the numbering with the part prefix? Or **do** you like it? It's not clear from you update. Also, what about adding a part heading in the LoF at the start of every part (as in Part I, Part II, ...)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would like to have (Part I, list of figures; Part II, list of figures, etc.), but I don't know how to get that!