# Chapter titles as hyperlinks in the list-of-figures

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, titletoc

I would like to include the chapter titles in my list of figures. @GonzaloMedina previously answered [this question using titletoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc). However, not all my chapters are numbered, so I would like the chapter titles in the lof to be shown just as they are in the toc.

This is Gonzalo Medina's preamble:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}  % or xpatch
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
% initial definitions of the chapter info (name and number)
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}%
  {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
\global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}

% the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a \chapter command, 
% it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \iftoggle{noFigs}{
       \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
    }{}
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

And creating the following document:

```
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\chapter{Preface with a figure}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

and

[image]

My questions are

1. How to surpress the preface's chapter number to be shown?
2. How to combine this with the `hyperref` package to let the chapters in the lof be hyperlinks?

Comment: This here seems interesting: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17344&f=44&sid=a29ceebb3e9a1f92425ff971ce5ddbb2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example controls the chapter numbering by counter `secnumdepth`. It also be used to define `\thischapternumber` with a special value (empty macro = `\@empty`), if the chapter number should be suppressed. The code in `\addtocontents` checks `\thischapternumber` to suppress `\numberline` if necessary.

The changes for `hyperref` are small. The anchor is remembered in `\thischapterHref` and used in `\contentsline`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}  % or xpatch
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
% initial definitions of the chapter info (name and number)
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}{%
  \gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}%
  \ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>-1 %
    \gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
  \else
    \global\let\thischapternumber\@empty
  \fi
  \global\let\thischapterHref\@currentHref % hyperref
  \global\toggletrue{noFigs}%
}{}{}

% the figure environment does the job: the first time it is used after a
% \chapter command, 
% it writes the information of the chapter to the LoF
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \iftoggle{noFigs}{%
      \addtocontents{lof}{%
        \protect\contentsline{chapter}{%
          \ifx\thischapternumber\@empty
          \else
            \protect\numberline{\thischapternumber}%
          \fi
          \thischaptertitle
        }{}{%
          \thischapterHref % hyperref
        }%
      }%
      \global\togglefalse{noFigs}%
    }{}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\chapter{Preface with a figure}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: How can I control the page breaks in the list of figures? Simply `\addtocontents{lof}{\clearpage}` didn't do it...

Comment: @D.Roepo: You can put `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\clearpage}` *inside* a figure environment before or after the caption, where you want to have the page break.