# List of Figures and List of Tables: How to divide into chapters with chapter headline?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want my List of Figures AND List of Tables to look kinda like this:

> ## List of Figures
>
> ### Chapter 1: Bla bla  bla
>
> 1.1 Lorem ipsum
>
> 1.2 dfgr grgr grgr
>
> 1.3 fgog gofrg afe
>
> ### Chapter 3: ROFL LOL MAO
>
> 3.1 fdef
>
> 3.2 dfd
>
> 3.4 df df d fd

You get the idea? If Chapter 2 do not contain figures, I do not want the headline of chapter 2 to be there.

I want the same for the List of Tables.

I once found something familiar on this site, but I cant find it right now. And as far as I can recall, that was only for the List of Figures

I'd be very grateful for all help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, dvipsnames,cmyk]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\include{chapters/contents}
\end{document}
```

I'm using a lot of other packages, but I'm not sure if they are relevant?

Comment: Hi and welcome, this is dependant on the class in use. The KOMA-classes `scrbook` and `scrreprt` have a simple option for that. But without [more information](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) there is nothing much to do.

Comment: I'm not using those. I'm new to LaTex, but maybe this will be of help:


\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, dvipsnames,cmyk]{report}

What else do you need?

Comment: Please follow the link in my first comment and add the information to the question. The button to edit is left to your name and user picture.

Comment: Done :). Anything else you need?

Comment: The KOMA classes will write every chapter to the lists if asked, this can be seen either as a sign of consistency (how does it look if one list contains chapters 3, 4 and 9; and another list chapter 5, 6 and 9?) but on the other hand, when starting a new chapter, there is no way to know if a figure will be typeset. You would need a hack that writes a `toggle` for every chapter to a auxiliary file reading it back on the next run.

Comment: What you want to do can be done automatically; some time ago I provided a solution in [`my answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52747/3954) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52746/3954.

Comment: @Johannes_B what is the simple option for `scrreprt`? Thanks in advance

Comment: @riddleculous To do what?

Comment: @Johannes_B: in your first comment you mentioned that there is an option in KOMA Script for doing what was asked in the question (sorting the list of figures/tables by the chapters).

Comment: @riddleculous `listof=chapterentry`

Comment: @Johannes_B: thanks! Unfortunately, it lists chapters without any figure/table, too.

Comment: @riddleculous Yes, as written in the manual. If you have chapter 3, 7 and 11 with figures, it will look like Freddy Kruger was at work and took something. Horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually add `chapter`s' entries you need. It's done like that:

```
\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{My chapter with Figures}
\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{My chapter with Tables}
```

so in your code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter with Figures and Tables}
\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{My chapter with Figures and Tables}
\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{My chapter with Figures and Tables}
This chapter contains Figures and Tables

\chapter{My chapter with Tables}
\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{My chapter with Tables}
This chapter contains Tables

\chapter{My chapter with Figures}
\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{My chapter with Figures}
This chapter contains Figures

\listoftables
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that'll work :). I combined it with some referencing and larger font:

'\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{{\large Chapter \ref{sec:    <label>}:\  \nameref{sec:<label>}}}'
'\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{{\large Chapter \ref{sec:    <label>}:\  \nameref{sec:<label>}}}'


This is working, and I dont have too many chapters. However, it should be possible to do this in another way, so that I dont have to paste it in the beginning of every chapter?

Comment: Maybe `scrreprt` class can help you. But I'm not sure. Try a search here: http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf