# How to organize a list of figures and tables corresponding to each section?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I need to organize both my list of figures and tables to adhere to two reports attached together, corresponding to each title of the reports, as it has to be one pdf file. I have seen hardly any material covering this, whereas any material I did find was overly complicated or simply did not work.

This is how I need the two Lists to appear (Note that I am using **sections** not chapters):

[image]

This is my LoF and LoT, where the red line indicates where I need the section title. Lab 2 is an exact copy of 1 so that I could test the LoF and LoT.

[image]

Mve below for main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
    }
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

  
\input{ArduinoCodeListing}

\begin{document}

\input{labCover.tex}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\input{Lab1}

\newpage
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\input{Lab2}

%\newpage
%\setcounter{section}{0}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
%\input{Lab3.tex}

%append more reports in the future...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that to see hat you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, I found exactly what I wanted on one post linked here:

[List of Figures and List of Tables: How to divide into chapters with chapter headline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211971/284162)