# Memoir: add chapter headings to 'list of...'

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am seeking to add chapter headings to my list of figures, tables etc. I could not find a solution in the `memoir` manual, although the solution is probably contained within it I do not know what I am looking for exactly so my apologies.

I have modified [RicoRally's EDIT solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211980/problem-with-automatic-chapters-parts-in-list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables) to apply to chapters but `memoir` is not detecting the titles or they are called something else which I do not know. The code with `\documentclass{memoir}` produces this lof:

[image: List of figures memoir class]

Whereas the code with `\documentclass{report}` produces this lof:

[image: List of figures Report class]

The code that I am using is:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}%
  {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \iftoggle{noFigs}{
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber.} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
    }{}
  }%
}

\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \gdef\my@caption{#2}
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}

\renewenvironment{figure}%
               {\@float{figure}}%
               {\end@float
               \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}%
                   {\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\my@caption}}%
               }%
\renewenvironment{figure*}%
               {\@dblfloat{figure}}%
               {\end@dblfloat
               \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}%
                   {\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\my@caption}}%
               }%
\makeatother

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Testing}
\lipsum
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{First figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
\caption{Second figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\chapter{Hallo}
\lipsum
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{First figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
\caption{Second figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I sort of get the gist of the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` although I do not understand what the `\long\def` section is doing. If anyone could help me add chapter headings to the `memoir` lof I would appreciate it.

Neither the `memoir` or `report` code works with `hyperref` either, it gives this error message:

```
Package hyperref Warning: old lof file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.

[1{c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...umberline {\thefigure }{\my@caption 
                                                  }}{\thepage }{\@currentHre...
l.60 \end{figure}
```

If someone could help me with that in the same breath I would sincerely appreciate it although I could ask it as a separate question if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your fieedback!!

Comment: Memoir doesn't use `\@chapter`.  It does however use `\@m@mchapter` where #1 contains the (short) title.

Comment: @JohnKormylo By changing `\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef`  from #1 to #2 the code worked perfectly as is, in case anyone in the future runs into this issue. Thank you for that, nice one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use     in chapters containing figures:

`\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\thechapter.\;~Testing}`

after  `\chapter{Testing}` and so on.

**UPDATED**

Use `\chapterlof` after any `\chapter{..}` with figures.

[image: d]

A simple memoir MWE with `hyperref`

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

%**************************** added
\makeatletter
\def\printchaptertitle#1{\chaptitlefont #1 \gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}}%
\makeatother

\cftsetindents{figure}{1.5em}{2.3em} %indent

\newcommand{\chapterlof}{\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\thechapter.\;~\thischaptertitle}}% add chapter to lof
%*****************************************
    
\begin{document}    

\listoffigures

\chapter{Testing}   
\chapterlof % add chapter to lof
\lipsum
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \caption{First figure}
    Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
    \caption{Second figure}
    Test
\end{figure}
\chapter{Hallo}
\chapterlof
\lipsum
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \caption{First figure}
    Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
    \caption{Second figure}
    Test
\end{figure}
\chapter{Bye}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was hoping for something more automatic as it is for my thesis which will have lof, lot, list of equations and list of chemical schemes (the beauty of doing chemistry/enzymes) but as that does indeed do what I need I will +1 and hold it in reserve whilst I try harder to work it out. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for that edit, that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I thank Simon Dispa for his answer and I note your comment about "something more automatic". The following is a version of Simon's answer that automatically adds chapters to the LoF

```
% chapinlofprob.tex  603616 (A modified version of Simon Dispa's answer)

\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

%**************************** added 
\newcommand{\chapterlof}{\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\thechapter.\;~\thischaptertitle}}% add chapter to lof

%%%% PW deleted
%\makeatletter
%\def\printchaptertitle#1{\chaptitlefont #1 \gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}}%
%\makeatother

\cftsetindents{figure}{1.5em}{2.3em} %indent

%*****************************************
    
\begin{document}    

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

%%%% PW added here
\makeatletter
\def\printchaptertitle#1{\chaptitlefont #1 \gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\chapterlof}%
\makeatother


\chapter{Testing}   
%\chapterlof % add chapter to lof PW deleted
\lipsum
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \caption{First figure}
    Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
    \caption{Second figure}
    Test
\end{figure}
\chapter{Hallo}
%\chapterlof % PW deleted
\lipsum
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \caption{First figure}
    Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
    \caption{Second figure}
    Test
\end{figure}
\chapter{Bye}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that if the definition of `\printchaptertitle` comes before the `\listoffigures` then various unnumbered chapter-like titles can be added to the LoF; that is why I put it just before the first numbered chapter.