# Hyperref causing errors with chapter headings in memoir list of's

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, memoir, undefined

I am trying to adapt some code so that I can have chapter headings in my list of figures, tables, equations and reaction schemes using the `memoir` document class. I [asked a question yesterday](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603616/memoir-add-chapter-headings-to-list-of) and received quality answers which I was very happy with and implemented until I checked out a comment by JohnKormylo which fixed the main issue of the question, that being how to get memoir to recognize the chapter titles as well as the chapter numbers (changing `\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}` to `{#2}` is the solution). This now skips the chapter 3 heading if there are no figures/tables etc in that chapter which is incredibly desirable to me.

[image: How I desire it to look]

The issue now is that the code is incompatible with `hyperref` and is producing the following error message:

```
(./Listoffigurestest.out) (./Listoffigurestest.out)

Package hyperref Warning: old lof file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.

[1{c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...umberline {\thefigure }{\my@caption 
                                                  }}{\thepage }{\@currentHre...
l.59 \end{figure}
                 
?
```

The error persists even when I delete the .aux files before running. I would appreciate it if anyone knew how to fix this please as I do not know latex enough at this moment although that will change with time. The minimal working example to produce the error is:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}%
  {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#2}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \iftoggle{noFigs}{
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber.} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
    }{}
  }%
}

\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \gdef\my@caption{#2}
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
%
\renewenvironment{figure}%
               {\@float{figure}}%
               {\end@float
               \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}%
                   {\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\my@caption}}%
               }%
               
\renewenvironment{figure*}%
               {\@dblfloat{figure}}%
               {\end@dblfloat
               \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}%
                   {\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\my@caption}}%
               }%
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Testing}
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{First figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
\caption{Second figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\chapter{Hallo}
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{First figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
\caption{Second figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\chapter{Bye}
\chapter{Bonjour}
\begin{figure}[b]
\caption{Second figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit: Solution to chapter headings being beneath the list of... entries**

When running the solution provided by Ulrike, the chapter headings on my list of's looked like this:

[image]

I am using a segmented file with `\include{}` and custom .sty packages so struggled to identify what was causing the error. Turns out the solution is to delete the code in your `\include{chapter1}` etc, save it and redo the code again. Not sure why this worked but so be it.

[image]

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: why do you redefine `\@caption`  and figure? That looks quite odd. Typically the caption writes the lof-entry, not the figure environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I copied and adapted the code from [RicoRally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211980/problem-with-automatic-chapters-parts-in-list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables) and applied it to chapters rather than parts, if I remove that section that it produces weird behaviour, I will modify my question to show what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho you are overcomplicating.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}%
  {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#2}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}


\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \iftoggle{noFigs}{%
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber.} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }%
      \global\togglefalse{noFigs}%
    }{}%
  }%
}

%

\makeatother



\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Testing}
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{First figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
\caption{Second figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\chapter{Hallo}
\section{Hallo}
\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{First figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
\caption{Second figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\chapter{Bye}
\chapter{Bonjour}
\begin{figure}[b]
\caption{Second figure}
  Test
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It was producing weird behaviour because I was accidentally commenting out \makeatother too when commenting out the \renewenvironments in my question, thanks for your help works perfectly. Amateur mistake to comment that out, now I know for the future.