# How to add a \chapter mark to a custom "list of..."?

Tags: table-of-contents, lists

After many years of reading other persons posts and 3 thesis written in latex, I finally post a question myself.

I have a document with blueprints (which are inlcluded as images or .pdf) organized in different chapters, so I have defined a custom "list of" in order to create a "Table of blueprints".

I can create the Table of Blueprints, and the blueprints themselves are included in it with no complication.

However, I´d also like to include in the Table of Blueprints the chapters under which the blueprints are, and for that purpouse I use the \addcontentsline command.

The problem is that in the Table of Bluepritns I can only get the chapter number (with \chaptername and \thechaper); I´ve tried to use \chaptermark but to no avail, as I get the following error:

> Argument of \chaptermark has an extra }. ...{pln}{chapter}{\thechapter : \chaptermark}

Therefore I´ve resorted to a manual solution by typing the chapter title manually in the \addcontentsline command, but I´d like t know if there is a way to make it automatic.

These are some of the posts I´ve checked [Add chapter headigns to list off...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603616/memoir-add-chapter-headings-to-list-of) ; [Include chapter headings in list of...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc) ; [automatic chapters in list of](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211980/problem-with-automatic-chapters-parts-in-list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables); I´ve tried following their code but I´m not certain where I have to look.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,tocbibind,tocloft}
%
% List of Blueprints creation
\newcommand{\listplano}{{\huge \textbf{Table of blueprints}}}% custom list of blueprints
\newlistof{plano}{pln}{\listplano}% plano=blueprint in Spanish
\newcommand{\plano}[1]{% custom command to create a new blueprint
\refstepcounter{plano}% counter
\par\noindent\textbf{Plano \theplano. #1}% caption
\addcontentsline{pln}{plano}{\protect\numberline{\theplano}#1}\par}% add the blueprint to the list of blueprints
%
\begin{document}    
%
\newpage
\tableofcontents
%
% List of blueprints
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of blueprints}% add an entry for the Table of blueprints to the ToC
\listofplano% print the list of blueprints
%
\chapter{Blueprints of Project X}
\addcontentsline{pln}{chapter}{\thechapter \, Blueprints of Project X}% add chapter to the list of blueprints; here is where I tried to use \chaptermark
\newpage
\plano{Project X - A}
Here I add the blueprint as an image or a pdf.
%
\chapter{Blueprints of Project Y}
\addcontentsline{pln}{chapter}{\thechapter \, Blueprints of Project Y}% add chapter   to the list of blueprints
\newpage
\plano{Project Y - 1}
 Here I add the blueprint as an image or a pdf.
 %
 \newpage
 \plano{Project Y - 2}
 Here I add the blueprint as an image or a pdf.
 %
 \end{document}
```

Thanks to anyone who may help. I´ve been consulting these forums for years and I´ve learned a lot from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really incorporate tjhe `\addcontentsline` into the definition of `\chapter`. Here's one way to manage that:

```
\NewCommandCopy{\oldchapter}{\chapter}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{ s +O{#3} +m }
   {
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}
         {\oldchapter*{#3}} % Starred chapter
         {                  % Non-starred chapter
           \oldchapter[#2]{#3}
           \addcontentsline{pln}{chapter}{\thechapter \, #2}
           \newpage
         }
   }
```

Then you can just write `\chapter` as if none of your changes were in place. This will also start the new page that you're currently doing manually.

Answer (score 1):

`\chaptermark` is executed by `\chapter` and is passed the (short) chapter title as an argument.  The good news is that you can modify it to save the chapter title to a macro (like `\chaptertitle`).  The bad news is that it gets redefined when you change pagestyles.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,tocbibind,tocloft}
%
% List of Blueprints creation
\newcommand{\listplano}{{\huge \textbf{Table of blueprints}}}% custom list of blueprints
\newlistof{plano}{pln}{\listplano}% plano=blueprint in Spanish
\newcommand{\plano}[1]{% custom command to create a new blueprint
\refstepcounter{plano}% counter
\par\noindent\textbf{Plano \theplano. #1}% caption
\addcontentsline{pln}{plano}{\protect\numberline{\theplano}#1}\par}% add the blueprint to the list of blueprints
%
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
        #1}}{}\xdef\chaptertitle{#1}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}    
%
\newpage
\tableofcontents
%
% List of blueprints
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of blueprints}% add an entry for the Table of blueprints to the ToC
\listofplano% print the list of blueprints
%
\chapter{Blueprints of Project X}
\addcontentsline{pln}{chapter}{\thechapter \, \chaptertitle}% add chapter to the list of blueprints; here is where I tried to use \chaptermark
\newpage
\plano{Project X - A}
Here I add the blueprint as an image or a pdf.
%
\chapter{Blueprints of Project Y}
\addcontentsline{pln}{chapter}{\thechapter \, \chaptertitle}% add chapter   to the list of blueprints
\newpage
\plano{Project Y - 1}
 Here I add the blueprint as an image or a pdf.
 %
 \newpage
 \plano{Project Y - 2}
 Here I add the blueprint as an image or a pdf.
 %
 \end{document}
```