# How can I modify LOT to look like my TOC [Pagestyle & Title position] (see example)

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbibind

so I have this problem that my LOT does not want to be like my TOC.. Can anybody help me? Heres the picture of my LOT and TOC:[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,table]{report}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla,english]{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand{\theAssignment}{ FedeCopters. }

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,inner=30mm]{geometry}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}         
    \pagestyle{fancy}            
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}        
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\lhead{Universidad Técnica Federico Santa María}\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\textbf{\thepage}}
\lfoot{Seguridad Operacional - \theAssignment}\chead{}
\rhead{Academia de Ciencias Aeronáuticas}

\usepackage[
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

%TOC APPEARANCE
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\makeatletter
\def\tableofcontents{%
 \newpage
 \centerline{\huge\scshape Índice} 
 \vspace*{0.3in}
 \@mkboth{CONTENTS}{CONTENTS}
 \@starttoc{toc}
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}        
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}      
\usepackage{secdot}

\usepackage{tabularx}

%--
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
%--
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\listoftables
\clearpage

\section*{Sobre FedeCopters}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Sobre FedeCopters}
blah.. blah..
\subsection*{Definición de la empresa}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Definición de la empresa}
blah....
.
.
.
\section*{Organigrama}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Organigrama}
...
\section*{Mapa de Procesos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Mapa de procesos}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \toprule
             a&b\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Procesos más relevantes de FedeCopters}
    \end{table}

\chapter{Procesos de FedeCopters.}
...
\chapter{Peligros y evaluación del riesgo asociado a las actividades...}

%Table example..
\begin{table}[!h]
     \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XX}
       \toprule
       a&b\\
       \midrule
       c&d\\
       \bottomrule
     \end{tabularx}
\caption[Peligros y riesgos del proceso: Evaluación de los requisitos del cliente]{blaaaah...}
\end{table}

.
\end{document}
```

I want LOT page to have header and footer... (I tried with \thispagestyle{fancy} but didn't work). I'd also like the title of LOT (Índice de tablas) to be just like the title of TOC (Índice). Thats all!

I'm using TexMaker on Windows 7.

I'd really appreciate if you guys can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you want your LOT's elements to be listed by chapter? If that's the case, maybe this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc  can help.

Comment: It seems that you want the indentation. But it won't make much sense as the tables are not classified as sections subsections etc. However, you may use `tocloft` package. In its manual, search for `\cftsetindents`.

Comment: @Drarp, I just modified the question, I just want page style and the title of LOT to be at the top center of the page.

Comment: @HarishKumar, as I was saying to Drarp, I just want pagestyle and the title of LOT at the top center of the page. Sorry guys for not specifying at the beggining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already loading `titlesec` so it may be better to use its facilities for this job. However, in your way, this is one possibility:

```
%TOC APPEARANCE
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\makeatletter
\def\tableofcontents{%
 \newpage
 {\centering\huge\scshape Índice\par}
 \vspace*{0.3in}
 \@mkboth{CONTENTS}{CONTENTS}
 \@starttoc{toc}
}
%% LOT appearence
\def\listoftables{%
 \newpage
 {\centering\huge\scshape Índice de tablas\par}
 \vspace*{0.3in}
 \@mkboth{TABLES}{TABLES}
 \@starttoc{lot}
}
\makeatother
```

[image]