# Retrieving page number of table for a "list of tables"-like list

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Let me please introduce a bit of context first: Building up from Gonzalo Medina's answer to [Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc?noredirect=1&lq=1), I added the same features to a List of Tables. While everything went fine with my List of Figures, the List of Tables got the chapter line (for each new chapter where a table occurs) saved to the `\jobname.lot` file *after* the line corresponding to the first table.

There is something related with the contents of the chapters in my document that leads to this weird result, as I've tried with exactly the same class and packages but with MWE-like chapters and everything went fine about the tables, too. This is the reason why I'm not asking here about the occurrence of this strange feature --it may be something lurking in my own chapter files, although I haven't been able to disclose what it may be and what I've been checking results in really weird stuff. Nonetheless, if somebody has seen the same feature occurring, any suggestions about its origin will be welcome.

I'm trying with a different approach: My class is based on `memoir` and I'm using a new file extension (`lotb`) to store the data about the chapters and the tables in the file `\jobname.lotb` using the same approach as put forward by Gonzalo Medina (except for a few minor changes based on `memoir`). Everything runs smoothly with this approach, but I don't know how I'm supposed to retrieve the page numbers for the tables in order to take them to the `\jobname.lotb` file.

What follows is an MWE, my true setting being much more complex than this.

Also, any suggestions on how to improve my approach overall would be very welcome.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
 \def\thischaptertitle{}
 \def\thischapternumber{}
 \def\thistabtitle{}
 \newtoggle{noFigs}
 \newtoggle{noTabs}

 %<- My new "list of"
 \def\listoftabsname{Tables}
 \newlistof{listoftabs}{lotb}{\listoftabsname}
 \def\tabsmark{\listoftabsname}

 \AtBeginDocument{%
   % I part ways slightly from Gonzalo Medina's answer by resorting 
   % to a memoir-based hook 
   \apptocmd{\memendofchapterhook}{%
     \gdef\thischaptertitle{\f@rtoc}%
     \gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
     \global\toggletrue{noTabs}%
     \global\toggletrue{noFigs}%
   }{}{}

   % This is going to be used to get the content of the caption of a table. 
   % But, how do I get the page number?
   % Plus, I guess it can be done much better than this 
   \apptocmd{\@caption}{%
     \gdef\thistabtitle{\@currentlabelname}%
     \gdef\thistabpage{}%<- How to?
   }{}{}

   % In my true setting I have to do this AtEnd, instead of AtBeginning
   \AtEndEnvironment{table}{%
     \iftoggle{noTabs}{
       \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
       \addtocontents{lotb}{%
         \protect\contentsline {chapter}%
         {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber}{\protect\ignorespaces\thischaptertitle}}{}{}
         \protect\vskip0.125\protect\baselineskip}%\addvspace{5\p@}}}
     }{}
   }
   % This goes AtEndEnvironment{table} in order to have the right counter value;
   % otherwise, it is lagging one unit behind; e.g., the first is \thechapter.0
   \AtEndEnvironment{table}{%
     \addtocontents{lotb}{%
       \protect\contentsline {table}%
       {\protect\numberline {\thetable}{\protect\ignorespaces\thistabtitle}}{\thistabpage}{}
       \protect\vskip0.125\protect\baselineskip}%\addvspace{5\p@}}}
   }%

   % Everything runs smoothly for the figures  
   \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
     \iftoggle{noFigs}{
       \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
         {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber}{\protect\ignorespaces \thischaptertitle}}{}{}
         \protect\vskip0.125\protect\baselineskip}%\addvspace{5\p@}}
       \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
     }{}
   }%
 }
\makeatother

% I'm using all of the packages below (and more) in my original setting.
% They appear here just because I think they can be relevant in order to provide a context 
% for any possible answers to work in my real-life scenario  

\usepackage[figurewithin=chapter,tablewithin=chapter]{caption}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toctitles,explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures*
\listoftabs
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}
  One
  \caption{One.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
    \caption{One.}
  One
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Oneb.}
  Oneb
\end{table}

\chapter{Two}

\begin{figure}
  Two
  \caption{Two.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  Two
  \caption{Two.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Three}

\begin{figure}
  Three
  \caption{Three.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  Threeb
  \caption{Threeb.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: My original problem, which brought all of the above on stage, has been solved with the approach I explain in my non-answer post below.

Comment: `\gdef\thistabpage{\thepage}` works for me, but your approach does not allow for hyperlinks

Comment: I had not even tried it! But your comment points to one of the reasons why I'm not fond of my hacking here. Any amendments would be great, including to my overall approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a normal `\addcontentsline` in the 2nd `\AtEndEnvironment{table}` is cleaner and easier, and it provides the correct hyperanchors as well. The additional vertical spacing is written with `\addtocontents`.

In fact, `\addcontentsline` is a wrapper for `\addtocontents{...}{\protect\contentsline{...}{...}{...}}`, letting it do whatever it is designed to do using the default style will guarantee the correct page numbers and hyperanchors are used.

In principle, the same could be done for the extra chapter lines in the `.lotb`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\thischaptertitle{}
\def\thischapternumber{}
\def\thistabtitle{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}
\newtoggle{noTabs}

% <- My new "list of"
\def\listoftabsname{Tables}
\newlistof{listoftabs}{lotb}{\listoftabsname}
\def\tabsmark{\listoftabsname}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % I part ways slightly from Gonzalo Medina's answer by resorting 
  % to a memoir-based hook 
  \apptocmd{\memendofchapterhook}{%
    \gdef\thischaptertitle{\f@rtoc}%
    \gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\toggletrue{noTabs}%
    \global\toggletrue{noFigs}%
  }{}{}

  % This is going to be used to get the content of the caption of a table. 
  % But, how do I get the page number?
  % Plus, I guess it can be done much better than this 
  \apptocmd{\@caption}{%
    \gdef\thistabtitle{\@currentlabelname}%
    \gdef\thistabpage{\thepage}%<- This is the how-to
  }{}{}

  % In my true setting I have to do this AtEnd, instead of AtBeginning
  \AtEndEnvironment{table}{%
    \iftoggle{noTabs}{
      \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
      \addtocontents{lotb}{%
        \protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber}{\protect\ignorespaces     \thischaptertitle}}{\thepage}{}
        \protect\vskip0.125\protect\baselineskip}%\addvspace{5\p@}}}
    }{}
   }
   % This goes AtEndEnvironment{table} in order to have the right counter value;
   % otherwise, it is lagging one unit behind; e.g., the first is \thechapter.0
   \AtEndEnvironment{table}{%
     \addcontentsline{lotb}{table}{\protect\numberline {\thetable}{\protect\ignorespaces     \thistabtitle}}
%     \addtocontents{lotb}{%
%       \protect\contentsline {table}%
%       {\protect\numberline {\thetable}{\protect\ignorespaces     \thistabtitle}}{\thistabpage}{\thetable.\theHtable}
     \addtocontents{lotb}{\protect\vskip0.125\protect\baselineskip}%\addvspace{5\p@}}}
   }%

   % Everything runs smoothly for the figures  
   \AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
     \iftoggle{noFigs}{
       \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
         {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber}{\protect\ignorespaces \thischaptertitle}}{}{}
         \protect\vskip0.125\protect\baselineskip}%\addvspace{5\p@}}
       \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
     }{}
   }%
 }
\makeatother

% I'm using all of the packages below (and more) in my original setting.
% They appear here just because I think they can be relevant in order to provide a context 
% for any possible answers to work in my real-life scenario  

\usepackage[figurewithin=chapter,tablewithin=chapter]{caption}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toctitles,explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures*
\listoftabs
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}
  One
  \caption{One.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
    \caption{One.}
  One
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Oneb.}
  Oneb
\end{table}

\chapter{Two}

\begin{figure}
  Two
  \caption{Two.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  Two
  \caption{Two.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Three}

\begin{figure}
  Three
  \caption{Three.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  Threeb
  \caption{Threeb.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much for going further than just the page topic and for the explanations provided.

Comment: @Marcos: You're welcome. Actually, the page number  issue puzzled me right from the start and then I wondered why `\addcontentsline` isn't used here. `\addtocontents` is the more powerful command of course to write 'anything' to a contents file, but care has to be taken if `hyperref` is involved, since `hyperref` extends `\contentsline` considerably!

Comment: Lists of contents are still amongst the least clear topics to me. Thanks again for the insights provided, which I believe will prove helpful in the future, too. Btw, in the midst of all the captioning macros and lists of contents stuff, using simply  `\thepage` didn't even come across my mind.

Comment: @Marcos: The reason why `\thepage` can be used is that the value of the `page` counter (or better: the formatting of the page counter value) is written explicitly at the position where `\addcontentsline` is used, i.e. it has the correct page value directly written to the contents file. See lines 5936f of `latex.ltx` for more information on this -- it's quite readable code there... and yes, I've have answered 'one' or 'two' ToC - related questions here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an amendment or an alternative approach than an answer to my post properly, but I think it may be useful to somebody anyway, and I like it much better than my original approach. It still borrows from Gonzalo Medina's contribution and, of course, from Christian Hupfer's --which I take as the answer to my post.

The basics of my current approach rely on hacking the captioning command instead of using the environments hooks. In this way I enhance the original approach insofar as the non-floats captioned via the `\captionof` command are also written to the corresponding list of contents, which was not the case by hacking the float-based environments. In my setting, it is all about table and non-floating tabular-like environments, which is why I make the hack testing (`\ifthenelse` command from the `xifthen` package) for table-based captions. The same can be done for figures. Of course, the hooks on the environments for the type of float considered are to be removed.

I introduce the hack below. For the sake of brevity I do not repeat the entire MWE, but if someone thinks I should type it entirely again, please feel free to let me know.

```
\apptocmd{\@caption}{%
  \gdef\thistabtitle{\@currentlabelname}%
  \gdef\thistabpage{\thepage}%
  %
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@captype}{table}}{%
    \iftoggle{noTabs}{%
      \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
      \addtocontents{lotb}{%
        \protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber}%
           {\protect\ignorespaces \thischaptertitle}}{}{}}%
      }{}%
      \addcontentsline{lotb}{table}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thetable}%
          {\protect\ignorespaces  \thistabtitle}}}{}
}{}{}
```

EDIT: Well, after testing the captioning hack for figures, too, I found that my original problem about the list of tables, which brought me here, was solved by using `\pretocmd` and forgetting about the hooks on to the environments. I don't even need a new list of contents anymore! Writing to the default list of tables (`\jobname.lot`) works perfectly. Thus, the "solve-it-all" hack for me is as follows, including both tables and figures (further code enhancements will be welcome):

```
\newcommand{\addchapterto}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
    \protect\contentsline {chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber}{\protect\ignorespaces \thischaptertitle}}{}{}}%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\vskip0.125\protect\baselineskip}%
}

\pretocmd{\@caption}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@captype}{table}}{%
    \iftoggle{noTabs}{
      \global\togglefalse{noTabs}
      \addchapterto{lot}
    }{}
  }{%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\@captype}{figure}}{%
       \iftoggle{noFigs}{
         \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
         \addchapterto{lof}
       }{}%
     }{}%
  }%
}{}{}
```

Comment: If you want to omit the pagenumbers for the chapter entries in the LoT you can use the `\addtocontents` approach, of course, otherwise, a simple `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{....}` would do to!