# Include chapters in List of Figures fails for appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I add contents lines containing the chapter numbers in the list of figures of a document, by using the third answer of the following question:

[Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc)

All is good except when I add an appendix, where I have the following error message:

`! Missing number, treated as zero.! You can't use \numexpr in horizontal mode. \ifnumcomp ...\ifnum \numexpr #1\relax #2\numexpr...`

but it compiles good ! so it gives the desired result despite the error message !

What's the cause of this error message, and how can I avoid it ?

I give the original file, where I only add the command for appendix:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}  %% ADDED TO THE ORIGINAL FILE

\makeatletter
\def\thischaptertitle{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}}{}{}

\newcommand{\DeclareDividedList}[1]%
  {\newcounter{#1@chapter}\setcounter{#1@chapter}{0}}

\pretocmd{\addcontentsline}%
  {\ifltxcounter{#1@chapter}%
   {%
     \ifnumgreater{\thechapter}{\value{#1@chapter}}{%
       \setcounter{#1@chapter}{\thechapter}%
       \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}%
         {\protect\numberline {\thechapter} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
     }{}%
   }{}%
  }{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareDividedList{lof}
\DeclareDividedList{lot}

\usepackage[paperheight=12cm,vscale=0.9]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures but no Tables}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Tables but no Figures}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures and Tables}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
%%% ADDED APPENDIX  
    \begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
    \chapter{Appendix One}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure 1 of appendix 1}
    \end{figure}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

and the result obtained:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: When you're using a counter in a comparison or to set a counter, you want to use `\value{counter}`, not `\thecounter`.  And watch out for counters resetting in the appendix.

`\thecounter` prints a text representation of that counter, but this is not necessarily a number (for example, the chapter becomes A).  This means that commands that expect a number see a letter instead ("Missing number..."), which led to your output having a spurious "A¿A" just before the caption.

But once you use `\value{counter}`, you run into an additional problem: because the chapter numbering starts over in the appendix, your `\ifnumgreater` no longer sees a larger number, and therefore doesn't write `\thischaptertitle`.  The solution is to reset the divided counter.  This leads to:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}  %% ADDED TO THE ORIGINAL FILE

\makeatletter
\def\thischaptertitle{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}}{}{}

\newcommand{\DeclareDividedList}[1]{%
  \newcounter{#1@chapter}%
  \setcounter{#1@chapter}{0}%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\setcounter{#1@chapter}{0}}% added
}

\pretocmd{\addcontentsline}%
  {\ifltxcounter{#1@chapter}%
   {%
     \ifnumgreater{\value{chapter}}{\value{#1@chapter}}{% \the -> \value{}
       \setcounter{#1@chapter}{\value{chapter}}% \the -> \value{}
       \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}%
         {\protect\numberline {\thechapter} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
     }{}%
   }{}%
  }{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareDividedList{lof}
\DeclareDividedList{lot}

\usepackage[paperheight=12cm,vscale=0.9]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures but no Tables}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Tables but no Figures}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures and Tables}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{caption text}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
%%% ADDED APPENDIX  
    \begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
    \chapter{Appendix One}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure 1 of appendix 1}
    \end{figure}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well done thank you